# ASP.NET MVC controller actions that return JSON or partial html

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, json, asp.net-ajax

I am trying to create controller actions which will return either JSON or partial html depending upon a parameter. What is the best way to get the result returned to an MVC page asynchronously?

Answer (score 552, accepted):

In your action method, return Json(object) to return JSON to your page.

```
public ActionResult SomeActionMethod() {
  return Json(new {foo="bar", baz="Blech"});
}
```

Then just call the action method using Ajax. You could use one of the helper methods from the ViewPage such as

```
<%= Ajax.ActionLink("SomeActionMethod", new AjaxOptions {OnSuccess="somemethod"}) %>
```

SomeMethod would be a javascript method that then evaluates the Json object returned.

If you want to return a plain string, you can just use the ContentResult:

```
public ActionResult SomeActionMethod() {
    return Content("hello world!");
}
```

ContentResult by default returns a text/plain as its contentType.
This is overloadable so you can also do:

```
return Content("<xml>This is poorly formatted xml.</xml>", "text/xml");
```

Comment: sorry phil! this doesnt actually answer the question does it? its definitely useful but as brad says you need to find out somehow what they are asking for and return the result accordingly.

Comment: see my somewhat related (well the one that led me here) question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/482363/should-my-mvc-controller-really-know-about-json

Comment: if you find an answer, link it in the question itself. Also i don't think checking this as the answer is the right thing.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/320291/how-to-post-an-array-of-complex-objects-with-json-jquery-to-asp-net-mvc-controll is related

Comment: What is the fully qualified name of that Json class?

Comment: @Haacked: I have read your [Json Hijacking](https://haacked.com/archive/2009/06/25/json-hijacking.aspx/) blog, would you be able to explain why changing `Get` to `Post` prevents the attack? I have asked this question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61995800/how-to-get-value-of-input-tag-in-javasctipt/61995917#61995917

Comment: Because the attack relies on the attacker using a script tag with the src set to your code. If your code only responds to POST, it won't get loaded in someone's script tag.

Answer (score 115):

I think you should consider the AcceptTypes of the request.  I am using it in my current project to return the correct content type as follows.

Your action on the controller can test it as on the request object

```
if (Request.AcceptTypes.Contains("text/html")) {
   return View();
}
else if (Request.AcceptTypes.Contains("application/json"))
{
   return Json( new { id=1, value="new" } );
}
else if (Request.AcceptTypes.Contains("application/xml") || 
         Request.AcceptTypes.Contains("text/xml"))
{
   //
}
```

You can then implement the aspx of the view to cater for the partial xhtml response case.

Then in jQuery you can fetch it passing the type parameter as json:

```
$.get(url, null, function(data, textStatus) {
        console.log('got %o with status %s', data, textStatus);
        }, "json"); // or xml, html, script, json, jsonp or text
```

Comment: Thanks James, that could be very useful for creating sort of a website and a REST API using the same Controller Actions.

Comment: If I have many methods like this in my controller is there any way that I can do this more generically?

Comment: In which namespace is the Json class ? What is the dependency for project.json ? Thanks in advance

Comment: That's the [JsonResult class from System.Web.Mvc](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.jsonresult(v=vs.118).aspx) (in System.Web.Mvc.dll) @Andrei

Comment: Thank you, found it. Maybe update the answer to reflect the new API? Btw, I'm using dotnet core where it's Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.JsonResult.

Answer (score 84):

Another nice way to deal with JSON data is using the JQuery getJSON function.  You can call the

```
public ActionResult SomeActionMethod(int id) 
{ 
    return Json(new {foo="bar", baz="Blech"});
}
```

Method from the jquery getJSON method by simply...

```
$.getJSON("../SomeActionMethod", { id: someId },
    function(data) {
        alert(data.foo);
        alert(data.baz);
    }
);
```

Comment: This does not answer the question at all.

Comment: @Aaronaught Actually the first part `return Json(new {foo="bar", baz="Blech"});` does!

Comment: Also consider $.post  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/751218/how-to-use-getjson-sending-data-with-post-method  ( ASP.Net MVC defaults to disable JSON Get requests for security reasons )

Answer (score 57):

I found a couple of issues implementing MVC ajax GET calls with JQuery that caused me headaches so sharing solutions here.

1. Make sure to include the data type "json" in the ajax call.  This will automatically parse the returned JSON object for you (given the server returns valid json).
2. Include the `JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet`; without this MVC was returning a HTTP 500 error (with `dataType: json` specified on the client).
3. Add `cache: false` to the $.ajax call, otherwise you will ultimately get HTTP 304 responses (instead of HTTP 200 responses) and the server will not process your request.
4. Finally, the json is case sensitive, so the casing of the elements needs to match on the server side and client side.

Sample JQuery:

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'get',
  dataType: 'json',
  cache: false,
  url: '/MyController/MyMethod',
  data: { keyid: 1, newval: 10 },
  success: function (response, textStatus, jqXHR) {
    alert(parseInt(response.oldval) + ' changed to ' + newval);                                    
  },
  error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    alert('Error - ' + errorThrown);
  }
});
```

Sample MVC code:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult MyMethod(int keyid, int newval)
{
  var oldval = 0;

  using (var db = new MyContext())
  {
    var dbRecord = db.MyTable.Where(t => t.keyid == keyid).FirstOrDefault();

    if (dbRecord != null)
    {
      oldval = dbRecord.TheValue;
      dbRecord.TheValue = newval;
      db.SaveChanges();
    }
  }

    return Json(new { success = true, oldval = oldval},
                JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Answer (score 12):

To answer the other half of the question, you can call:

```
return PartialView("viewname");
```

when you want to return partial HTML. You'll just have to find some way to decide whether the request wants JSON or HTML, perhaps based on a URL part/parameter.

Comment: so doesnt the question remain unanswered?

Comment: This does not answer the question.

Comment: he is looking for a ajax request to get the html using PartialView requires a page refresh unless you are return the view from an action method using an ajax call

Answer (score 7):

Alternative solution with [incoding framework](https://incframework.codeplex.com/)

Action return json

**Controller**

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult SomeActionMethod()
    {
        return IncJson(new SomeVm(){Id = 1,Name ="Inc"});
    }
```

**Razor page**

```
@using (var template = Html.Incoding().ScriptTemplate<SomeVm>("tmplId"))
{
    using (var each = template.ForEach())
    {
        <span> Id: @each.For(r=>r.Id) Name: @each.For(r=>r.Name)</span>
    }
}

@(Html.When(JqueryBind.InitIncoding)
  .Do()
  .AjaxGet(Url.Action("SomeActionMethod","SomeContoller"))
  .OnSuccess(dsl => dsl.Self().Core()
                              .Insert
                              .WithTemplate(Selector.Jquery.Id("tmplId"))
                              .Html())
  .AsHtmlAttributes()
  .ToDiv())
```

Action return html

**Controller**

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult SomeActionMethod()
    {
        return IncView();
    }
```

**Razor page**

```
@(Html.When(JqueryBind.InitIncoding)
  .Do()
  .AjaxGet(Url.Action("SomeActionMethod","SomeContoller"))
  .OnSuccess(dsl => dsl.Self().Core().Insert.Html())
  .AsHtmlAttributes()
  .ToDiv())
```

Answer (score 6):

You may want to take a look at this very helpful article which covers this very nicely!

Just thought it might help people searching for a good solution to this problem.

http://weblogs.asp.net/rashid/archive/2009/04/15/adaptive-rendering-in-asp-net-mvc.aspx

Answer (score 5):

PartialViewResult and JSONReuslt inherit from the base class ActionResult. so if return type is decided dynamically declare method output as ActionResult.

```
public ActionResult DynamicReturnType(string parameter)
        {
            if (parameter == "JSON")
                return Json("<JSON>", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            else if (parameter == "PartialView")
                return PartialView("<ViewName>");
            else
                return null;


        }
```

Answer (score 3):

For folks who have upgraded to MVC 3 here is a neat way
[Using MVC3 and Json](http://geekswithblogs.net/michelotti/archive/2008/06/28/mvc-json---jsonresult-and-jquery.aspx)

Comment: you can also use the same technique as this article in MVC 2

Answer (score 2):

```
    public ActionResult GetExcelColumn()
    {            
            List<string> lstAppendColumn = new List<string>();
            lstAppendColumn.Add("First");
            lstAppendColumn.Add("Second");
            lstAppendColumn.Add("Third");
  return Json(new { lstAppendColumn = lstAppendColumn,  Status = "Success" }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
        }
```

Comment: could you add a Little more Information about what this does?

Comment: Since your code shows it's return JSON, the return type should be JsonResult and not ActionResult

Answer (score 2):

Flexible approach to produce different outputs based on the request

```
public class AuctionsController : Controller
{
  public ActionResult Auction(long id)
  {
    var db = new DataContext();
    var auction = db.Auctions.Find(id);

    // Respond to AJAX requests
    if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
      return PartialView("Auction", auction);

    // Respond to JSON requests
    if (Request.IsJsonRequest())
      return Json(auction);

    // Default to a "normal" view with layout
    return View("Auction", auction);
  }
}
```

The `Request.IsAjaxRequest()` method is quite simple: it merely checks the HTTP headers for the incoming request to see if the value of the X-Requested-With header is `XMLHttpRequest`, which is automatically appended by most browsers and AJAX frameworks.

Custom extension method to check whether the request is for json or not so that we can call it from anywhere, just like the Request.IsAjaxRequest() extension method:

```
using System;
using System.Web;

public static class JsonRequestExtensions
{
  public static bool IsJsonRequest(this HttpRequestBase request)
  {
    return string.Equals(request["format"], "json");
  }
}
```

Source : https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/programming-aspnet-mvc/9781449321932/ch06.html#_javascript_rendering