# ASP.NET MVC: How to create an action filter to output JSON?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, json, action-filter

My second day with ASP.NET MVC and my first request for code on SO (yep, taking a short cut).

I am looking for a way to create a filter that intercepts the current output from an Action and instead outputs JSON (I know of [alternate approaches](http://weblogs.asp.net/omarzabir/archive/2008/10/03/create-rest-api-using-asp-net-mvc-that-speaks-both-json-and-plain-xml.aspx) but this is to help me understand filters). I want to ignore any views associated with the action and just grab the ViewData["Output"], convert it to JSON and send it out the client. Blanks to fill:

`TestController.cs:`

```
[JSON]
public ActionResult Index()
{
    ViewData["Output"] = "This is my output";
    return View();
}
```

`JSONFilter.cs:`

```
public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
{
   /*
    * 1. How to override the View template and set it to null?
    * ViewResult { ViewName = "" } does not skip the view (/Test/Index)
    * 
    * 2. Get existing ViewData, convert to JSON and return with appropriate
    * custom headers
    */
}
```

Update: Community answers led to a fuller implementation for a [filter for JSON/POX](http://aleembawany.com/2009/03/27/aspnet-mvc-create-easy-rest-api-with-json-and-xml/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest that what you really want to do is use the Model rather than arbitrary `ViewData` elements and override `OnActionExecuted` rather than `OnActionExecuting`.  That way you simply replace the result with your `JsonResult` before it gets executed and thus rendered to the browser.

```
public class JSONAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
   ...

    public override void OnActionExecuted( ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
    {
        var result = new JsonResult();
        result.Data = ((ViewResult)filterContext.Result).Model;
        filterContext.Result = result;
    }

    ...
}

[JSON]public ActionResult Index()
{
    ViewData.Model = "This is my output";
    return View();
}
```

Comment: Thanks. 1 line needs to be corrected to ((ViewResultBase)filterContext.Result)).ViewData.Model. However, the Index() action still shows the view associated with it (Views/Test/Index) instead of showing the JSON blob even though  filterContext.Result has correct value.

Comment: Doing this in OnActionExecuted overrides the view and achieves what I was after.

Comment: Hmmm.  I would have thought that replacing the result just before it was rendered would have been the proper time.  I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 3):

You haven't mentioned only returning the JSON conditionally, so if you want the action to return JSON every time, why not use:

```
public JsonResult Index()
{
    var model = new{ foo = "bar" };
    return Json(model);
}
```

Comment: The [JSON] attribute is being used to turn JSON on or off on certain actions but this is more of an exercise as I mentioned. In an actual implementation I would probably inspect the request http headers to determine response type.

Answer (score 0):

maybe this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/320291/how-to-post-an-array-of-complex-objects-with-json-jquery-to-asp-net-mvc-controll) could help you the right way. The above post is also a method