# How can I turn off this warning about how MVC can't find my view?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, filter

I wrote a filter to return jsonp from a controller action based on some headers and what-not. Problem is, the IDE doesn't know this and it's warning me that I need to create a view or whatever. It's not a big deal, but I'm tired of explaining it to FNGs.

[image: the word "View" is in red]

Note: I'm swapping the view out to "Shared/Format/" + format.cshtml, depending on the headers and other factors to use a view to render the callout function and some custom json rendering. The filter makes all that happen, but I still want to return an ActionResult so I can use the view to do some last-minute formatting.

How do I make `"View"` stop being red?

Comment: I think you need to use `JsonResult` as the return type.

Comment: edited to help explain why I'm not doing that

Comment: See related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/686753/asp-net-mvc-how-to-create-an-action-filter-to-output-json

Answer (score 0):

IF you're tyring to return JSON, try this:

```
public JsonResult Save(...) {
    // ...
    return Json(new [] {success});
}
```

If not (as per your comment), maybe this will help: [ASP.NET MVC: How to create an action filter to output JSON?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/686753/asp-net-mvc-how-to-create-an-action-filter-to-output-json)

I suppose you can adapt to use in your `JSONP` filter.

Comment: the accepted answer to that question would still produce the warning

Comment: Its not a valid `View` so we need some other approach. I'll get to it tonight.