# What are the best practices for manual MediaTypeFormatter management in ASP MVC Web API?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, mediatypeformatter

I have ASP MVC Web API service and my method should return data in a specific format (JSON, XML, etc.). The response format depends on the method and doesn't depend on client preferences.

I use `HttpResponseMessage` and `ObjectContent` and need to set MediaTypeFormatter for `ObjectContent`.

I can do it this way:

```
new ObjectContent<MyDataContract>(data, new JsonMediaTypeFormatter())
```

or this way:

```
new ObjectContent<MyDataContract>(
    data, 
    Configuration.Formatters
        .FirstOrDefault(f => f.GetType() == typeof(JsonMediaTypeFormatter))
)
```

None of them look particularly good. The first one creates a new object for each request. The second one uses a search/filter and it looks inappropriate here.

What is a better solution for my problem?

Comment: I wouldn't worry to create a new object for each request unless it impacts in a measurable way. Anyway nothing stops you to save it in a `[ThreadLocale]` static variable or, easier, with `static ThreadLocal<JsonMediaTypeFormatter> _jsonMediaTypeFormatter;`

Comment: "I'm using Web API and my method should return JSON" - no.  Your method should return the data type that has been requested, you can make this json by default:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/20556625/2181514

Comment: "None of them look pretty" - welcome to MVC!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I get ASP.NET Web API to return JSON instead of XML using Chrome?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9847564/how-do-i-get-asp-net-web-api-to-return-json-instead-of-xml-using-chrome)

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti `JsonMediaTypeFormatter` is already saved at  `Configuration.Formatters` so I don't think that this idea much more better. I haven't any serious issues with my solution but I want it to be more beauty :)

Comment: @freedomn-m I have requirements that some my method should return JSON, some XML and it shouldn't depend on client preferences

Comment: ...and you can't directly pick it through Configuration.Formatters.JsonMediaTypeFormatter, yes, you just avoid the search. That's why I wouldn't bother with this (unless you have reasons to make it thread-safe).

Comment: Then just return JSON/XML as a string from the action (ie encode in the action) and forget about using MediaTypeFormatters.   If it's *sometimes* JSON, *sometimes* XML, then it's no good changing the default values.

Comment: @freedomn-m it always XML and always JSON for each method. Serialize it manually and return as string (or byte array) is really interesting idea. Thank you

Comment: Here's another option for you:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/686753/asp-net-mvc-how-to-create-an-action-filter-to-output-json  return the data as normal, then use an actionfilter (attribute on the action) to convert to JSON/XML just before sending it back to the client.  This means you don't have lots of `return Json()` but you do instead have `[Json]` applied to the action definition.

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti watch out on recommending `[ThreadLocal]` to people. It doesn't work well when used in async contexts. For modern code that needs isolation, it is best to rely on `[AsyncLocal]` instead.

Comment: @julealgon good point, this is from 8 years ago so I'm not sure about the context anymore but if OP was already using MVC 4 and .NET 4.6 then for sure!

Answer (score 0):

You can set in webApiConfig file.

```
  config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.Add(new MediaTypeHeaderValue("text/html"));
```

Also it is also possible to set MediaType for response while returning data -

```
     [HttpGet]
      public HttpResponseMessage GetJson()
      {

        var result = new List<string>();

        for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++)

            result.Add("Hello World");

       return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, result, new 
        MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json"));

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest approach to have full control over the return format on a per-action basis is just to leverage the `IActionResult` implementations.

Use `JsonResult` to always return json-formatted output using whatever serializer you have configured by default.

- [JsonResult Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.jsonresult?view=aspnetcore-7.0)
- [JsonResult Class legacy MVC version](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.jsonresult?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2)

```cs
return new JsonResult(data);
```

Use a custom `IActionResult` implementation for XML or a library version that provides one to you such as:

- [Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters.Xml.Extensions](https://www.nuget.org/packages/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.formatters.xml.extensions/6.0.0)
- [MvcContrib (for legacy MVC)](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MvcContrib)

This provides you with the `XmlResult` type which can be returned in a similar way.

The idea behind these abstractions is that you don't need to take care of manual serialization in your controller code, but the implementations will still force a specific format using the underlying serializers configured in AspNetCore that skips content negotiation for format.

Answer (score -1):

Why you do not use IHttpActionResult and return Ok()? Do you need HttpResponseMessage explicitly? Also do you want to always return JSON or not depending on the content type the client expects?

If you want to always return JSON and using IHttpActionResult in your WebApiConfig file you can add the following:

```
config.Formatters.Clear();
config.Formatters.Add(new JsonMediaTypeFormatter());
```

This way the API will always return JSON and in your controller you can only return OK:

```
return this.Ok(data); // will be enough, no need to specify the content type
```

Otherwise, if you insist on HttpResponseMessage, you can inherit ObjectContent class and use it (code is written on the fly, may need some tweeks)

```
public class JsonObjectContent<T> : ObjectContent<T>
{
    public JsonObjectContent(T data) : base(data, new JsonMediaTypeFormatter())
    {
    }
}
```

And in your controller you will say

```
new JsonObjectContent<MyDataContract>(data)
```

Comment: I updated my question and now it should be more clear. `JsonObjectContent` still create new formatter per each request.

Comment: Well, with the updated question, the first comment by Adriano Repetti looks fine with me, if you do not want to instantiate the formatter each request.

Comment: A significant portion of this answer goes against the OP requirements to have per-method control over the format and does not apply.