# Post an array of complex objects with JSON, JQuery to ASP.NET MVC Controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json, jquery

I know this issue has been touched on before, e.g. here:

[How to post an array of complex objects with JSON, jQuery to ASP.NET MVC Controller?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/320291/how-to-post-an-array-of-complex-objects-with-json-jquery-to-asp-net-mvc-controll)

But the solutions doesn't seem to fit my problem.

Here is my HTML. The number of rows are variable:

```
 <table id="workPlanTable">
    <tr>
        <th>
            Begin
        </th>
        <th>
            End
        </th>
    </tr>

    <tr itemId="1">
        <td><input class="begin" id="begin_1" name="begin_1" type="text" value="5:30" /></td>
        <td><input class="end" id="end_1" name="end_1" type="text" value="11:30" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr itemId="3">
        <td><input class="begin" id="begin_3" name="begin_3" type="text" value="5:30" /></td>
        <td><input class="end" id="end_3" name="end_3" type="text" value="7:30" /></td>
    </tr>

</table>
```

The JS builds an array of objects and posts them to a control method:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {

  submitForm = function() {
    var items = new Array();
    $("#workPlanTable tr").each(function(i) {
      var end = $(this).find(".end").val();
      var begin = $(this).find(".begin").val();
      var item = {
        "Begin": begin,
        "End": end
      };
      items.push(item);

    });
    var postData = {
      myItems: items
    };

    $.ajax({
      url: '~/WorkPlan/AjaxUpdate',
      type: 'POST',
      dataType: 'json',
      data: postData,
      contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
      success: function(result) {
        alert(result.Result);
      }
    });
  }
})
</script>
```

Each row represent a WorkPlanItem that.

My goal is to post them all to my controller to update them.

I can't seem to figure out how to access the array in my controller method (AjaxUpdate).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can serialize the form as [Vikas posted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/760249/post-an-array-of-complex-objects-with-json-jquery-to-asp-net-mvc-controller/760384#760384), or you could use a `stringify` [function](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/json2.js) if you'd prefer to walk the page (as you are currently doing) and use the `postData` array.

On the controller, you'll need to handle the json string. You can use the `System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer` [class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.aspx) to deserialize it. If you have an object that maps to the data you're passing, you can use the [Deserialize](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.aspx) method. If you don't, you can still use [DeserializeObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.deserializeobject.aspx), however that gives you a `Dictionary<string, string>` collection that you'll have to walk through to get your data. Not exactly fun (trust me), but it works.

Comment: Thanks for a great answer.
I ended up using the stringify function + JavaScriptSerializer