# Post Array as JSON to MVC Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, json, asp.net-mvc-4

I have been struggling to find a solution to this problem.

In my code, I am building up an array of an object;

```
var $marks = [];

var mark = function ( x, y, counter ){
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.counter = counter;
}

$marks.push(new mark(1, 2, 0));   
$marks.push(new mark(1, 2, 1));
$marks.push(new mark(1, 2, 2));
```

Now I want to post this data to a MVC controller, so I would think that the data type in the controller would be a `List<Mark> Marks` or an array of Marks.

To post the data, I have tried;

```
var json = JSON.stringify($marks);
$.post('url', json).done(function(data){ /* handle */ });
```

OR

```
var json = { Marks: $marks };
$.post('url', json).done(function(data){ /* handle */ });
```

The second way, when looking at the data posted, looks like this

```
Marks[0][x]: 1
Marks[0][y]: 2
Marks[0][counter]: 0
Marks[0][x]: 1
Marks[0][y]: 2
Marks[0][counter]: 1
Marks[0][x]: 1
Marks[0][y]: 2
Marks[0][counter]: 2
```

But I am not sure how to translate this into a strongly typed object in the controller?

My Controller looks like this;

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult JsonSaveMarks(List<Mark> Marks){
    // handle here
}
```

My Mark class looks like this;

```
public class Mark{
     public string x { get; set; }
     public string y { get; set; }
     public string counter { get; set; }
}
```

I have read through other similar problems about creating a custom [JsonFilterAttribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/320291/how-to-post-an-array-of-complex-objects-with-json-jquery-to-asp-net-mvc-control), or using the [System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/760249/post-an-array-of-complex-objects-with-json-jquery-to-asp-net-mvc-controller) class, but I cant get anything to work

Is there something obvious I am missing here? Have I got the DataType in the controller completely wrong? How can I convert this data posted into a strongly typed object?

Many Thanks

Comment: what does your Mark-class in MVC look like?

Comment: @Pbirkoff I have updated the question with the class

Comment: check this question, especially the first answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4789481/post-an-array-of-objects-via-json-to-asp-net-mvc3

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`$.post()` doesn't allow you to set the content type of your AJAX call - you might find (if you use Fiddler) that your Json string is being sent with a content-type of "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" (the default setting) which then causes Asp.Net MVC to incorrectly interpret your data packet.

Can you try using `$.ajax()` instead, and set the content type to "application/json"?

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: Ah, you beat me to it, had the same idea

Comment: Thanks! After all that headache I knew it would be something simple! changed my code to using `$.ajax()` also, passed the data through as `JSON.stringify($marks)`

Comment: Thanks so much. It was the content type in my case.

Answer (score 14):

@SteveHobbs has the right answer here. On the other hand, you should `JSON.stringify` the JavaScript payload as you did. If you do it the other way, you will get an exception telling something like *"Invalid JSON primitive"* while deserializing the data coming in.

Here is the complete solution to your sample:

```
$.ajax({

    url: '/home/index',
    type: 'POST',
    data: JSON.stringify($marks),
    dataType: 'json',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

This code fixed my problem:

C# classes:

```
public class MediaAccountContent
{
    public Guid IdMedia { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }

}

public class User
{
    public string Firstname { get; set; }
    public string Lastname { get; set; }
    public List<MediaAccountContent> MediaAccountContents { get; set; }
}
```

MVC action:

```
public ActionResult SavePlace(User user)
{

    return Content("OK");
}
```

Javascript:

```
    var mediaAccountsJson = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        mediaAccountsJson.push({
            IdMedia: i,
            Value: "AAA" + i
        });

    }

    var datatItem =
    {
        Firstname: "Test Firstname",
        Lastname: "Test Lastname",
        MediaAccountContents: mediaAccountsJson
    };

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        data: JSON.stringify(datatItem),
        url: urlAction,
        success: function (status) {



        }
    });
```

Make the changes you need for your scenario and enjoy! :)

Comment: this code only post json object not an object array