# [MVC3]Can't bind JSON array

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, model-binding

I thought MVC3 can bind JSON data to model by default.

but this code

server:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Save(IList<int> IDs)
{
    return null;
}
```

client:

```
$.post('@Url.Action("Save", "Users")', {'IDs' : [1, 2, 3]}, function() {});
```

don't work. Why ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code sends `IDs[]=1&IDs[]=2&IDs[]=3`.

You need send `IDs=1&IDs=2&IDs=3`.

Set `traditional:true` parameter to use the traditional style of param serialization.

```
$.ajax({
    url: '@Url.Action("Save", "Users")',
    type: 'post',
    data: {'IDs' : [1, 2, 3]},
    traditional:true,
    success: function() {
        // ...
    }
})
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to send your data as application/json:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    url: '/Users/Save'
    data: JSON.stringify({'IDs' : [1, 2, 3]}),
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    success: function() {
       // ...
    }
});
```

Comment: Zoltan's code works fine, and setting of content type is not required.

Answer (score 0):

This might be the same as the problem I ran into a while ago. Check out this SO question [Post Array as JSON to MVC Controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10007722/post-array-as-json-to-mvc-controller)

Answer (score 0):

You have to apply `JSON.stringify`

```
$.post('@Url.Action("Save", "Users")', JSON.stringify({'IDs' : [1, 2, 3]}), function() {});
```