# how to pass an array of strings from jQuery to controller

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

How can I pass an array of strings to a controller in asp.net mvc4?

Here is my code

**jQuery:**

```
function FnSaveAnalyses(){
    var checked = [];
    for (var i in checkedIds) {
        if (checkedIds[i]) {
            checked.push(i);
        }
    }
    alert(checked); // it shows all the records without problem

    var url = urlBiologieDemande + "Save";
    $.post(
                url,
                data = { values: checked},
                traditional= true,
                success = function (data) {
                    DataSaved();
                });
}
```

**Controller**

```
public ActionResult save(string[] values)
        {
            //Traitement
        }
```

When debugging, I get null values.

Comment: try to change your data just on data = checked (without values property)

Comment: the same problem always null :(

Comment: can you check exact Request body which has been sent to server? You may use Fiddler or Firefox with Firebug installed for this.

Comment: teh post request is undefined

Comment: Hm... let's do next call: $.post(url, { 'values[]': checked }, function (data) { DataSaved(); });

Answer (score 1, accepted):

POST IT AS JSON array.

```
var checked = [];
for (var i in checkedIds) {
    if (checkedIds[i]) {
        checked.push(i);
    }
}
var url = urlBiologieDemande + "Save";
$.ajax({
    type: 'Post',
    dataType: 'json',
    url: url ,
    data: JSON.stringify(values:checked),
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    async: false,
    success: function (data) {

    }
});
```

then get the JSON in the Controller 
and Parse it ..
see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12572856/jquery-post-array-asp-net-mvc-4)