# A Class with 2 list to MVC 4 Controler with ajax

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4

i've tried to send a class with two list with ajax to an mvc controler.

MVC Controler :

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult AfficherDetailsFacture(AfficheDetails afficheDetailsFacture)
{ 
   // do some stuff
}
```

C# Class for the controler argument:

```
[Serializable]
public class AfficheDetails
{

    public List<long> firstList{ get; set; }

    public List<long> secondList{ get; set; }

    public string numFacture{ get; set; }
}
```

JS :

```
var AfficheDetails = {
    firstList: [31025,6954], 
    secondList:  [31542,31211,23214,23211],
    numFacture: "Facture 001"
};    

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    async: false,
    url: urls.urlAfficherDetailsFacture,
    contentType: 'application/json',
    data: JSON.stringify(AfficheDetails),
    success: function (oResultat) {
      //
    }
```

This is NOT working properly.

If firstlist has less element than secondList, then firstList is null in the MVC controller.

i've been working several hours to discover this **"rule"**. If firstList has more element or the same ammount, it is working !

Is it a MVC Binding bug ?

Comment: take a look on this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12572856/jquery-post-array-asp-net-mvc-4)

Comment: @SergeyBoiko : this answer is with a single list, in this case it is not working all the time, but it is working some time. And i've the contentType arg.

Comment: That seems like a very strange "rule". Have you tried taking a look at what is actually sent across the wire (using Fiddler or a debugger in your browser)? Does removing the secondList property from the model make a difference?

Comment: @Rune i've check the data send with firebug, it is always good. If i remove the second list, it working all the time.

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteHENRY don't know what is the issue,try with the AfficheDetails.serializeArray() instead of JSON.Stringify .

Answer (score 1):

You can also use on Controller

```
public JsonResult AfficherDetailsFacture(string jsonData)
{ 
 var jss = new JavaScriptSerializer();
 var data = jss.Deserialize<AfficheDetails>(jsonData);
   // do some stuff
}
```

where data now contains all the values of the class `AfficheDetails`

and on Jquery

***edit*** the line

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    async: false,
    url: urls.urlAfficherDetailsFacture,
   // contentType: 'application/json',  comment the type
    data: { jsonData : JSON.stringify(AfficheDetails) },
    success: function (oResultat) {
      //
    }
```

Comment: i've tried this, but the arg is always null. i have not search further in this.

Comment: thanks it may work, but create a JS object and do nothing more was my goal. in this case it's working most of the time, i just not understand why the "rule" first < second apply ?