# Parse Array of JSON Objects in ASP.Net

Tags: jquery, asp.net, json

I am trying to learn ASP.Net MVC and I wanted to post array of JSON objects to the server and sent it back to the client side. Everything is fine when I use [Postman](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman-rest-client/fdmmgilgnpjigdojojpjoooidkmcomcm?hl=en), but it doesn't work on actual web page. I think the problem is either with jQuery code that posts the array or ASP.Net code that is not able to parse the array.

[image]

Here is my controller code:

```
[System.Web.Mvc.HttpPost]
public ActionResult GetResult(List<Table> list)
{
    return Json(list);
}
```

Here is my object declaration:

```
public class Table
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public String Question { get; set; }
    public int Answer { get; set; }
}
```

Here is jQuery code that posts the data:

```
$.post("./GetResult", JSON.stringify(tableData), function (data, status) { alert(status); }, "json");
```

and tableData is an Array of JSON like this:

```
[
    {
        "Id": 500,
        "Question": "where are you from",
        "Answer": 2
    },
    {
        "Id": 501,
        "Question": "how old are you",
        "Answer": 1
    },
    {
        "Id": 502,
        "Question": "what is your first car",
        "Answer": 2
    },
    {
        "Id": 503,
        "Question": "do you have kids",
        "Answer": 1
    }
]
```

Also, I can see that my code goes through the post controller but it is empty or null.
[image]

[Here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/wg5x9c4e5qos1em/SurveryEdit.cshtml?dl=0) is the link of my csHTML file.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Post Array as JSON to MVC Controller](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10007722/post-array-as-json-to-mvc-controller)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to specify content-type in your request:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "./GetResult",
  type: "POST",
  data: JSON.stringify(tableData),
  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
  dataType: "json",
  success: function (data, status) { alert(status); }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to `JSON.stringify` in your `$.post` call. Let jQuery handle that for you.

Comment: Without `JSON.stringify` this is what jQuery is sending to the server:  undefined=&undefined=&undefined=&undefined=

Comment: @Apha can you reproduce that in a fiddle?

Answer (score 0):

```
$.post("./GetResult", {list:tableData},
    function (data, status) 
    { 
        alert(status); 
    }
, "json");
```

Json never passed object.

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
[HttpPost]
Public ActionResult GetResult(string list)
{
    var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Table>>(strStatus);
    return Json(list)
}
```

**or**

```
$.ajax({
  url: "./GetResult",
  type: "POST",
  data: JSON.stringify(tableData),
  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
  dataType: "json",
  success: function (data, status) { alert(status); }
})
```