# How to deserialize json array data in ASP.NET MVC controller

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc

I had successfully deserialized a simple json object but when I send an array of json object using a POST request to my controller, it fails. Here is my code:

```
[HttpPost]
public string addWwarehouse([FromBody] warehouse warehouses)
{
      System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(warehouses[0].name);
      return "success";
}
```

This is working json data:

```
{
    "warehouses":
    {
        "name":"WarehouseA",
        "location":"locationA"
    }
}
```

But when I use an array like this,

```
[{
    "warehouses":
    {
        "name":"WarehouseA",
        "location":"locationA"
    }
}]
```

It doesn't work. I also tried using `List<warehouse>` but still no luck. This is my `warehouse` class:

```
public class warehouse { 
    public string name  { get; set; }
    public string location { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: What have you investigated? See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10007722/post-array-as-json-to-mvc-controller) SO question for example.

Comment: thankx for helping but in this question the request is not converted into json object but in my case it is as i already used `JSON.stringify`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the way that your json is, you need a class like this:

```
public class Warehouses
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string location { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public Warehouses warehouses { get; set; }
}
```

Then, in your action shoud be like this:

```
public string addWwarehouse([FromBody] RootObject warehouses)
```

I think this will resolve.

Comment: Try a list of RootObject in your action: public string addWwarehouse([FromBody] List<RootObject> warehouses)

Comment: Yes sir it is working but can you explain how as we dont have anything like `RootObject` in our json data ?

Comment: RootObject is just the name of the class, you can change for anything that makes more sense for you. What I did was, I took your json and converted to a c# class using that site: http://json2csharp.com/ and after that I realized that your json is inside of [] brackets, what means that you need a list of your class in your action.

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to StackOverflow.

It doesn't because your model is not a `List<warehouse>`:

```
[{
    "warehouses":
    {
        "name":"WarehouseA",
        "location":"locationA"
    }
}]
```

It is an array of objects *each* with a property called "warehouses" that contains a singular object of type `warehouse`. You might want to send an array of warehouses instead:

```
[{
    "name":"WarehouseA",
    "location":"locationA"
}, {
    "name":"WarehouseB",
    "location":"locationB"
}]
```

And deserialize it to `List<warehouse>`

P.S.
If you have no control over json format then the answer by @Tiago Ávila should do the trick.

Let's inspect the model:

```
[{                                // [...] - array of some outer objs
    "warehouses":                 // with single property
    {                
        "name":"WarehouseA",      // inner obj that resides inside outer obj
        "location":"locationA"
    }
}]
```

Comment: Sir I already tried this approach but the problem is my json request is created like the above array as mentioned starting with `[]` brackets so is there any approach i could do to deserialize it  ?