# Unable to access posted variable with jQuery JSON POST to WCF with DTO in wrappedrequest

Tags: jquery, asp.net, wcf, post

I'm trying to post values to my WCF service via a jQuery AJAX call. Right now I have a single parameter that I'm trying to post. When I post the data, the correct service is called, but when I try to access the object `str` I get the error `Object reference not set to an instance of an object`.
How can I fix this?

I've already looked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1123093/wcf-posting-jsonized-data) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6904609/consuming-wcf-from-jquery-as-json).

My code:

```
  $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: '/api/addlocationfavorite',
      data: JSON.stringify({locationid: 543}),
      contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
      dataType: "json",
      done: function (msg) {
          alert('done!');
      }
  });


<Runtime.Serialization.DataContract>
Public Class SimpleLocation
    <Runtime.Serialization.DataMember>
    Public Property locationid() As Integer
        Get
            Return locationid
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Integer)
            _locationid = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private _locationid As Integer
End Class


    <OperationContract()>
    <Web.WebInvoke(Method:="POST", ResponseFormat:=Web.WebMessageFormat.Json, BodyStyle:=Web.WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest,
UriTemplate:="addlocationfavorite")>
    Function addLocationFavorite(ByVal str As SimpleLocation) As Stream 


   Public Function addLocationFavorite(ByVal str As SimpleLocation) As Stream Implements Ilocation.addLocationFavorite
        LogError("addLocationFavorite") '<-- this line is executed

        LogError("addLocationFavorite str.locationid: " + str.locationid.ToString) '<--- this line throws error: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

    End Function
```

I tried with and without quotes around the parameter name "locationid", but it shows the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for your method to accept the JSON object you will need to define it like so:

```
 { str: { locationid: 543 } }
```

'str' being the name of the parameter your method accepts, this will allow it to deserialize the JSON into your `SimpleLocation` object.

```
 $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: '/api/addlocationfavorite',
      data: JSON.stringify({ str: { locationid: 543 } }), 
      contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
      dataType: "json",
      done: function (msg) {
          alert('done!');
      }
  });
```

The other problem here was with the locationid property. It was returning the property instead of the field.

```
Get
    Return locationid
End Get
```

it should be:

```
Get
    Return _locationid
End Get
```

Comment: Ok, doing that at least makes the `str` variable not nothing on the server side. However, when trying to access the `locationid` property of the `str` variable like so: `str.locationid.ToString` it returns value `0`. So it seems it's not being deserialized correctly? How to overcome that?

Comment: Wow...rookie mistake from me...but thanks, that did the trick :)