# Post array to ASP.NET MVC 2 Controller using AJAX

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, json

There is [known trouble](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/309115/how-can-i-post-an-array-of-string-to-asp-net-mvc-controller-without-a-form) with sending array to ASP.NET MVC controller. I've found a lot of solutions like [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/320291/how-to-post-an-array-of-complex-objects-with-json-jquery-to-asp-net-mvc-controll). Why don't use usual object instead array? It works good.
Example of code:

```
    <script>
    $(function(){
        $('.asArray').click(function(){
            var array = Array();
            array[0] = 'Dima';
            array[1] = 'Ann';
            array[2] = 'John';
            $.post('/Home/Get', {data: array}, function(data){alert(data);});
        });
        $('.asObject').click(function(){ // works good
            var array = Object();
            array[0] = 'Dima';
            array[1] = 'Ann';
            array[2] = 'John';
            $.post('/Home/Get', {data: array}, function(data){alert(data);});
        });
    });
</script>
<div>
    <input type="button" class="asArray" value="asArray"/>
    <input type="button" class="asObject" value="asObject"/>
```

controller action:

```
public ActionResult Get(IEnumerable<string> data)
    {
        if (data == null)
            return Content("data == null");
        return Content("data = [" + data.Aggregate((agr, curr) => agr + ", " + curr) + "]");
    }
```

Comment: The question is what people think about this solution? Maybe somebody know contraindications.