# asp.net mvc - pass javascript class into POST request

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

I tried to pass *Array* of javascript classes in **$.post** function, but in controller function, each member of list(argument) has default values.

JS code(View).

```
function CashCollectionModel() 
{
     this.Nominal = 0;
     this.NominalCount = 0;
     this.CriticalBalance = 0;
}
function SendRequest()
{
    var arr = new Array();

    var cash_nominal = new CashCollectionModel();

    cash_nominal.Nominal = 10;
    cash_nominal.NominalCount = 100;
    cash_nominal.CriticalBalance = 20;

    arr.push(cash_nominal);

    $.post('<%= Url.Action("EditCashCollection", "Terminals") %>', 
    {
         nominals : arr
    });
}
```

Server code(model) :

```
namespace TerminalsExtension.Presentation.Models
{
    public class CashCollectionModel
    {
       public long Nominal {set;get;}
       public long NominalCount {set;get;}
       public long CriticalBalance {set;get;}
    }
}
```

Controller function

```
public partial class TerminalsController : SharedControllerBase
{
   [Authorize]
   [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
   public ActionResult EditCashCollection(List<CashCollectionModel> nominals) 
   {
          // each member of "nominals" has 0 value


          return ExtView("CashCollection");
   }
}
```

How I can pass *Array* of javascript class into POST request and success retrieve it in controller ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[How to post an array of complex objects with JSON, jQuery to ASP.NET MVC Controller?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/320291/how-to-post-an-array-of-complex-objects-with-json-jquery-to-asp-net-mvc-controll)

May be this will help