# Model binder does not convert json to IEnumerable<T>

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json, modelbinder

I am sending json data to my controller action via jquery ajax post. The IEnumerable in my action is alway null.

Is my json wrong or why does the model binder not convert the json to the IEnumerable ?

```
public ActionResult Update(IEnumerable<Teststep> teststeps)
{
   //
}

$.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("Update", "Teststep")',
            type: 'POST',
            data: [{ "errortext": "oh something bad happended.", "unitid": "10" }, { "errortext": "you got it man.", "unitid": "20"}],
            success: function (response) {
                debugger;
                if (response.success) {
                    dlg.dialog("close");
                    // Update UI

                }
                else {
                    // Reload the dialog with the form to show model/validation errors 
                    dlg.html(response);
                }
            }
        });

public class Teststep
{

 [HiddenInput(DisplayValue = false)]
 public int UnitId { get; set; }    

 public string ErrorText { get; set; }  

 // some other props removed for readability   

}
```

Comment: Try to use **Teststep[] teststeps** as parameter for method
and serialize JSON: 
JSON.stringity([{ "errortext": "oh something bad happended.", "unitid": "10" }, { "errortext": "you got it man.", "unitid": "20"}])

Comment: Sorry I dont get the "Try to use Teststep[] teststeps as..." Can you rewrite that please?

Comment: `public ActionResult Update(Teststep[] teststeps)`

Comment: Could you provide `Teststep` class content?

Comment: ah I always thought as parameter for the json... now it makes sense :P, but it did not work still null the parameter. I also added Teststep class content.

Comment: Try to pass the following as data:
`data: [{ "ErrorText": "oh something bad happended.", "UnitId":"10"}]`

Comment: I have this now:  data: JSON.stringify([{ "ErrorText": "oh something bad happended.", "UnitId": "10"}]), and this: public ActionResult Update(Teststep teststep)
        {} and the teststep object is created but the properties like ErrorText are null.

Comment: Looks like there is only one way to do it: [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/320291/how-to-post-an-array-of-complex-objects-with-json-jquery-to-asp-net-mvc-control[link]

Comment: No thats not a solution for now. It was in MVC1/2 but not in MVC3 with the modelbinder this should work!

Answer (score 1):

In order to get collections (arrays, ienumerables, etc) to pass correctly through the modelbinder to the action method, I've always had to set the traditional: true option on the ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '@Url.Action("Update", "Teststep")',
    type: 'POST',
    traditional: true,
    ...
```

Comment: I doubt it. I've only been passing enumerations of primitives, not complex types. It works great using `.serialize()` instead of `.stringify()`. In your case stringify might be better since it appears you want to specify the values manually rather than get them from form input elements.

Comment: well I just tried this: var data = [ '11', '22' , '33' ]; JSON.stringify(data) and my action has an IEnumerable<string>. I get a count of 3. So it works. Wether I specifiy them manually for test purposes because I do not yet know the datagrid I will use later or I get the data from input elements via .val() should play no role.

Comment: Your answer also includes the `dataType: 'json'` parameter, whereas your original question does not. You may be able to achieve the same result by simply using the `traditional: true` option instead of `dataType: 'json'`. I have never encountered a reason to submit the POST data as a serialized JSON string in MVC. The default model binder should extract your collection parameters as long as you tell jQuery to do a shallow encoding. Deep object recursion was introduced in jQuery 1.4: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.param/

Comment: the dataType: 'json' can be removed. Jquery can infer its datatype. Only the contentType is needed.

Answer (score 1):

Now it works! I get 1 item in the IEnumerable. The problem was the messed up json ;-)

```
 var data = { teststeps: [{ ErrorText: 'bla', UnitId: 10}] };
        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("Update", "Teststep")',
            type: 'POST',
            data: JSON.stringify(data),
            dataType: 'json',
            contentType: 'application/json'            
        });

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Update(IEnumerable<Teststep> teststeps)
{

}
```