# MVC multi select not returning List<int>

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0

When I debug in javascript I see the value of $("#widgetIds").val() is an array of int values such as [1,2,3,4]. When it hits the controller the widgetIds List is null. 
I have tried:

- Using .serialize() and .serializeArray() in javascript
- Changing the widgetIds type to a List`<string>` on the controller
- Changing the widgetIds type to an int[] on the controller
- Changing the widgetIds type to a string[] on the controller
- Hours of little tweaks that didn't work or made things worse
- Google
- Yelling at my monitor
- Slamming my fist on my desk
- Beer

NOTE: I'm using this [multiselect](http://www.erichynds.com/jquery/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget/) control. The reason for the optgroups is for separation in the multiselect.

JavaScript

```
function ProcessButtonClick(){
$.post(processWidgetsUrl, { widgetIds: $("#widgetIds").val() });
}
```

View

```
<select id="widgetIds" name="widgetIds" multiple="multiple">
    <optgroup label="Big Widgets">
        @foreach (var widget in Model.Widgets.Where(d => d.WidgetCategoryId == 1))
        {
            <option value="@widget.Id">@widget.DisplayName</option>
        }
     </optgroup>

     <optgroup label="Little Widgets">
         @foreach (var widget in Model.Widgets.Where(d => d.WidgetCategoryId == 3))
         {
             <option value="@widget.Id">@widget.DisplayName</option>
         }
     </optgroup>

     <optgroup label="Red Widgets">
         @foreach (var widget in Model.Widgets.Where(d => d.WidgetCategoryId == 4))
         {
             <option value="@widget.Id">@widget.DisplayName</option>
         }
     </optgroup>

     <optgroup label="Blue Widgets">
         @foreach (var widget in Model.Widgets.Where(d => d.WidgetCategoryId == 5))
         {
             <option value="@widget.Id">@widget.DisplayName</option>
         }
     </optgroup>

     <optgroup label="Round Widgets">
         @foreach (var widget in Model.Widgets.Where(d => d.WidgetCategoryId == 6))
         {
             <option value="@widget.Id">@widget.DisplayName</option>
         }
     </optgroup>

     <optgroup label="Square Widgets">
         @foreach (var widget in Model.Widgets.Where(d => d.WidgetCategoryId == 7))
         {
             <option value="@widget.Id">@widget.DisplayName</option>
         }
     </optgroup>
 </select>
```

Controller

```
public virtual ActionResult ProcessWidgets(List<int> widgetIds)
{
    return Json(_widgetComponent.DoStuff(widgetIds));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to tell the server that you are sending it Json, then ASP.NET MVC will know how to properly interpret the data before it sends it to the controller:

```
function ProcessButtonClick(){
  $.post(processWidgetsUrl, { widgetIds: $("#widgetIds").val() }, null, "json");
}
```

You might need to convert your array to proper JSON [How to post an array of complex objects with JSON, jQuery to ASP.NET MVC Controller?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/320291/how-to-post-an-array-of-complex-objects-with-json-jquery-to-asp-net-mvc-control)

Comment: Thanks! Adding json didn't work for me. I will check out that article and let you know if that works.