# Passing a parameter of type List to Javascript function

Tags: javascript, list

I have a function in my view, that requires calling a list, in order to execute the ajax call within it. The API that I'm using has a parameter `List<>` among its arguments. That's why I need it.

Is it possible to pass a parameter of type `List<>` to a Javascript function? If yes, what's the appropriate syntax to use? I googled and didn't find an answer yet.

EDIT : Here's my code

Javascript function:

```
    function DeleteRoom(RoomId, FloorId, userDevicesID) {
        $.ajax({
            beforeSend: function (xhr) {
                xhr.setRequestHeader('verifySession', verifySession());
                xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', '@HttpContext.Current.Session["BaseAuth"]');
            },
            url: "/api/Room/RemoveRoom?RoomId=" + RoomId + "&userDevicesId="+ userDevicesID,
            type: "DELETE",
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data) {
                // removing items from the view
            }
        });
    }
```

Calling the popup that uses this function:

```
     arr.push(existingdevices[i].attrs.id); //array of IDs, can be empty
     PopUpDeleteRoom(id, FloorId, arr);
```

The API:

```
    [HttpDelete]
    public void RemoveRoom(int roomId, [FromUri]List<int> userDevicesId)
    {
        int currentUserId = SessionData.CurrentUser.UserID;
        List<Equipment> equipmentsAssociated = equipmentRepository.FindMany(e => e.RoomID == roomId).ToList();
        foreach (Equipment equipment in equipmentsAssociated)
        {
            equipment.RoomID = null;
            equipmentRepository.Update(equipment);
            equipmentDeviceRepository.DeleteAllEquipmentDeviceOfZwave(equipment.EquipmentID);
        }
        foreach (int userDeviceId in userDevicesId)
        {
            userDeviceRepository.Delete(userDeviceId); 
            //this generates a NullReferenceException that I will fix later
        }
        equipmentRepository.Save();
        userDeviceRepository.Save();
        roomRepository.Delete(roomId);
        roomRepository.Save();
    }
```

Please is there a solution or a workaround for this issue?

Comment: List<> or JSON, if you print the list you say? it will be useful

Comment: It's a list of integers (IDs) that I will pass to the function, the function is about deleting those instances by their IDs using an API.

Comment: With 'List', do you mean [`Live/ Static Nodelist or Array`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/NodeList)? This matters because the methods are different for both

Comment: Well, I'm confused now. I used a List for my API, and an Array for the js function.. Please see the edit, I think I messed up too much with my code

Comment: The syntax List<int> is new to me. Can anyone point out which language is tht?

Comment: C#, this is an MVC app.

Comment: There's no List type in javaScript. Either there's Array or Object (I mean `{ }`). However to send any of these as parameters, I suggest you use `data:` option available in jQuery `$.ajax` function

Comment: Oh I see. Didn't know that, thx. And I guess List and Array aren't convertible to each other. So I'll have to change the parameter's type to Array and try to fix the rest.

Comment: Take a look at this before you proceed. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/320291/how-to-post-an-array-of-complex-objects-with-json-jquery-to-asp-net-mvc-control

Answer (score 3):

I assume that in your javascript the `List<>` is an `Array`.

If that is the case, you can do all sorts of things with it: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_arrays.asp

Example (calling this function will display an alert for each element in the array):

```
var alertAllElements = function (theArray) {
    for(var x=0; x<theArray.length; x++)
        alert(theArray[x]);
};
```

Comment: Can I pass this Array parameter as a parameter to an API inside the function that I use in an ajax call? this API needs a parameter of type List (as its description in the controller says). That's what I need.

Comment: That's impossible to say without knowing what the API is, becuase we don't know how it's implementation works.  
It be easier if you show your code, and said what actual API you are calling.