# Convert to List<T> or T[] from Json array in C#

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, deserialization, json-deserialization

I have a json data:

```
"{\"list\":[{\"PlId\":1,\"PstId\":1,\"MonthlyValue\":\"00,00\"},{\"PlId\":2,\"PstId\":1,\"MonthlyValue\":\"00,00\"},{\"PlId\":3,\"PstId\":1,\"MonthlyValue\":\"00,00\"},{\"PlId\":4,\"PstId\":1,\"MonthlyValue\":\"00,00\"},{\"PlId\":5,\"PstId\":1,\"MonthlyValue\":\"00,00\"}]}"
```

I want to the json data convert to List but JsonConvert.Deserialize(jsonData) return null.

```
[Serializable]
public class DecryptedMonthlyPremiumScale
{
    [DataMember]
    public int PlId { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public int PstId { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string MonthlyValue { get; set; }
}
```

I tried this method: [How to post an array of complex objects with JSON, jQuery to ASP.NET MVC Controller?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/320291/how-to-post-an-array-of-complex-objects-with-json-jquery-to-asp-net-mvc-control)

What is wrong? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a wrapper class to deserialize properly:

```
[Serializable]
public class DecryptedMonthlyPremiumScale
{
    [DataMember]
    public int PlId { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public int PstId { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string MonthlyValue { get; set; }
}

public class Root
{
    public IList<DecryptedMonthlyPremiumScale> list {get;set;}
}

var obj = JsonConvert<Root>(json);
```

Another approach is to use `JObject` to get the root element and then deserialize:

```
var parsed = JObject.Parse(json)["list"].ToObject<IList<DecryptedMonthlyPremiumScale>>();
```