# how to bind json data to existing viewmodel - mvc5

Tags: c#, json, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-viewmodel

I have a long strongly-typed form which its inputs are bound with viewmodel as html helpers, while i have a table that's not strongly-typed, it's generated when user clicks Add button, and i collect its data  as json. how to map json data to viewmodel and send as one unit to post action in controller in ajax call?

view

```
@model SIServices.ViewModels.SODViewModel
@using (Html.BeginForm("Initiate", "SOD", FormMethod.Post, new { id = 
  "initiateSOD" })) // enctype = "multipart/form-data"
 {
      @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

      ...

      @* form inputs as html helpers *@
      @* html table data is collected as json *@
```

javasctipt

```
   var cols = [];
   cols.push("DIGITAL_FILE_TYPE_ID");
   cols.push("DOCUMENT_LAPI_ID");
   var DigitalMaps = [];
   $("table#digital-map-table tbody tr").each(function () {
   data = {};

   var selectedDigitalMapVal = $(this).data("selectedDigitalMapVal");
   data[cols[0]] = selectedDigitalMapVal;
   var documentId = $(this).data("documentID");
   data[cols[1]] = documentId.toString();                       
   DigitalMaps.push(data);
   data = {};

   });

    var headers = { __RequestVerificationToken: 
      $('input[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val() };

                if (DigitalMaps != null) {
                    $.ajax({
                        headers: headers,
                        url: "@Url.Action("Initiate")",
                        type: "POST",
                        cache: false,
                        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                        data: DigitalMaps,
                        dataType: "json",
                        success: function (succ) {
                            console.log(succ);
                        },
                        error: function (err) {
                            console.log(err.statusText);
                        }
                    });
                }
```

viewmodel

```
   namespace SIServices.ViewModels
   {
       public class SODViewModel
       {
          // a lot of properties - around 50
          public int? DigitalMapId { get; set; }
          public List<DIGITAL_MAPS> DigitalMaps { get; set; }
```

controller

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateHeaderAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Initiate(SODViewModel vm)
    {
```

Comment: Check the link below to see if it will solve your issue
[Halycon Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13242414/passing-a-list-of-objects-into-an-mvc-controller-method-using-jquery-ajax)

Comment: @SamuelAkosile thank you, I already pass json data to controller successfully, if the controller method argument is not of type viewmodel. my issue is, my viewmodel already has data from view, how to add a json object to it, and keep the old values?

Answer (score 0):

You've got a form, backed by the view model, which you need to convert to a JavaScript Object so you can attach the `DigitalMaps` array.

To tackle the first problem you can use one of the answers here [Convert form data to JavaScript object with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1184624/convert-form-data-to-javascript-object-with-jquery).

Below, I use the function from here https://stackoverflow.com/a/22420377/2030565. This worked on a simple form but I haven't tried to find edge cases.

```
$.fn.serializeObject = function() {
    var o = {};
    var a = this.serializeArray();
    $.each(a, function() {
        if (o[this.name]) {
            if (!o[this.name].push) {
                o[this.name] = [o[this.name]];
            }
            o[this.name].push(this.value || '');
        } else {
            o[this.name] = this.value || '';
        }
    });
    return o;
};
```

So we can capture the form and convert it to a JavaScript object:

```
var model = $("form").serializeObject();
```

Now we can attach the property for the collection:

```
var digitalMapRows = [];
model.DigitalMaps = digitalMapRows;
```

Then post with ajax

```
$.ajax({
    headers: headers,
    url: "@Url.Action("Initiate")",
    type: "POST",
    cache: false,
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    data: JSON.stringify(model),
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (succ) {
        console.log(succ);
    }        
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I handled the issue by collecting table data as JS array of objects, then stringify it, set a hidden field to stringified json, binding hidden field to viewmodel, to send digitalMaps with viewmodel, and deserialize the string into List<DIGITAL_MAPS> an controller post action and save it in db.

Comment: The form is very long, couldn't let go of viewmodel since it has a lot of data annotation attributes that i'm counting on for validation