# How to use getJSON, sending data with post method?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, post, http-post, getjson

I am using above method & it works well with one parameter in URL.

e.g. `Students/getstud/1` where controller/action/parameter format is applied.

Now I have an action in Students controller that accepts two parameters and return a JSON object.

So how do I post data with `$.getJSON()` using post method?

Similar methods are also acceptable.

The point is to call an action of the controller with AJAX.

Comment: `get` in `getJSON` means *use GET* to get some json.

Comment: @Majid Fouladpour When I asked this question, I wasn't knowing that..!

Answer (score 230, accepted):

The $.getJSON() method does an HTTP GET and not POST.  You need to use [$.post()](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/jQuery.post)

```
$.post(url, dataToBeSent, function(data, textStatus) {
  //data contains the JSON object
  //textStatus contains the status: success, error, etc
}, "json");
```

In that call, `dataToBeSent` could be anything you want, although if are sending the contents of a an html form, you can use the [serialize](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/serialize) method to create the data for the POST from your form.

```
var dataToBeSent = $("form").serialize();
```

Comment: Just want to add that $.getJSON support Jsonp(cross domain access) unfortunately $.post not.

Comment: Actually .getJSON() supports cross domain access in two ways. JSONP, which doesn't use GET or POST but script injection; but also CORS - and .post() also supports CORS. However CORS requires that the server also support it whereas JSONP does not.

Comment: Not true, JSONP also requires server support to parse the callback parameter.

Comment: When I am using the above function, I am receiving a string object instead of a json object.

Answer (score 12):

This is my "one-line" solution:

```
$.postJSON = function(url, data, func) { $.post(url+(url.indexOf("?") == -1 ? "?" : "&")+"callback=?", data, func, "json"); }
```

In order to use jsonp, and POST method, this function adds the "callback" GET parameter to the URL. This is the way to use it:

```
$.postJSON("http://example.com/json.php",{ id : 287 }, function (data) {
   console.log(data.name);
});
```

The server must be prepared to handle the callback GET parameter and return the json string as:

```
jsonp000000 ({"name":"John", "age": 25});
```

in which "jsonp000000" is the callback GET value.

In PHP the implementation would be like:

```
print_r($_GET['callback']."(".json_encode($myarr).");");
```

I made some cross-domain tests and it seems to work. Still need more testing though.

Comment: This will never bypass the limit GET has while POST maximum size can be redefined.

Comment: Why did you add `?callback`? in url? That made the callback not to be called for me. I also added `JSON.stringify(data)`. +1, helpful post!

Comment: @IonicăBizău: thanks. In order to return an object, we need to add "callback" parameter to the URL and the server needs to return the same object name generated by JQuery. I also use an override function for getJSON(): `jQuery.getJSON = function(url, data, func) { return $.get(url+(url.indexOf("?") == -1 ? "?" : "&")+"callback=?", data, func, "json"); }`

Answer (score 8):

Just add these lines to your `<script>` (somewhere after jQuery is loaded but before posting anything):

```
$.postJSON = function(url, data, func)
{
    $.post(url, data, func, 'json');
}
```

Replace (some/all) `$.getJSON` with `$.postJSON` and enjoy!

You can use the same Javascript callback functions as with `$.getJSON`.
No server-side change is needed. (Well, I always recommend using `$_REQUEST` in PHP. http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.request.php, [Among $_REQUEST, $_GET and $_POST which one is the fastest?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1924939/php-request-vs-get-and-post))

This is simpler than @lepe's solution.

Comment: This didn't work with the done() and fail() methods that you can normally apply to getJSON.

Answer (score 3):

I had code that was doing getJSON. I simply replaced it with post. To my surprise, it worked

```
   $.post("@Url.Action("Command")", { id: id, xml: xml })
      .done(function (response) {
           // stuff
        })
        .fail(function (jqxhr, textStatus, error) {
           // stuff
        });



    [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult Command(int id, string xml)
    {
          // stuff
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

I just used post and an if:

```
data = getDataObjectByForm(form);
var jqxhr = $.post(url, data, function(){}, 'json')
    .done(function (response) {
        if (response instanceof Object)
            var json = response;
        else
            var json = $.parseJSON(response);
        // console.log(response);
        // console.log(json);
        jsonToDom(json);
        if (json.reload != undefined && json.reload)
            location.reload();
        $("body").delay(1000).css("cursor", "default");
    })
    .fail(function (jqxhr, textStatus, error) {
        var err = textStatus + ", " + error;
        console.log("Request Failed: " + err);
        alert("Fehler!");
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

`$.getJSON()` is pretty handy for sending an AJAX request and getting back JSON data as a response. Alas, the jQuery documentation lacks a sister function that should be named `$.postJSON()`. Why not just use `$.getJSON()` and be done with it? Well, perhaps you want to send a large amount of data or, in my case, IE7 just doesn’t want to work properly with a GET request.

It is true, there is currently no `$.postJSON()` method, but you can accomplish the same thing by specifying a fourth parameter (type) in the `$.post()` function:

My code looked like this:

```
$.post('script.php', data, function(response) {
  // Do something with the request
}, 'json');
```

Answer (score -8):

if you have just two parameters you can do this:

```
$.getJSON('/url-you-are-posting-to',data,function(result){

    //do something useful with returned result//
    result.variable-in-result;
});
```

Comment: i think this is not the answer to what has been asked.