# PHP $_REQUEST Variable

Tags: php, post, get, request

I have a question regarding the $_REQUEST global variable in php. When you have a get and a post submitted with the same variable name does php assign priority to either of them? Ie. if I have $_POST['var'] as well as $_GET['var'] submitted to a page would $_REQUEST['var'] contain the post or the get or would it do some other type of assignment?

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It depends on the [**`request_order`**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.request-order) configuration directive *(quoting)* :

> This directive describes the order in which PHP registers GET, POST
> and Cookie variables into the `_REQUEST` array.

Also take a look at [`variables_order`][2] : some additional explanations *(like the letters that can be used)* are there -- and it also affects `$_REQUEST`.

Answer (score 0):

your question is quite similiar to the following post...check it out...

[Among $_REQUEST, $_GET and $_POST which one is the fastest?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1924939/php-request-vs-get-and-post)