# PHP escape special character in URL param

Tags: php, escaping

I working out to remove special characters in passing parameters through an URL in case to avoid injection by intruders, for example I had the URL below:

```
www.sitename.com/people?job=manager
```

I added an `alert` script after the parameter like below:

```
www.sitename.com/people?job=manager"/><script>alert%2844749%29<%2fscript>
```

when I run the URL, the `alert` will popup, this might cause vulnerability in retrieve site information by this technique. I will use `$_REQUEST` to get the passing parameter to generate results. Is that any cure to escape URL injection techniques which I can apply to below?

```
$job = $_REQUEST["job"];
```

Thanks for advise.

Comment: Why does the alert pop up if you simply have this **in the URL**?! Are you outputting this as is into HTML?

Answer (score 5):

You need to use `htmlentities()` or `htmlspecialchars()` with `ENT_QUOTES` parameter, on all your variable.

For example for `$job` :

```
$job = htmlentities($_REQUEST["job"], ENT_QUOTES);
```

Don't need to escape special characters in url params.

Answer (score 1):

First of all [don't use $_REQUEST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1924939/php-request-vs-get-and-post) and to protect against CSRF attacks you can either use `html_entities()` or `strip_tags()`.

If you want certain tags to be allowed you can use [HTML purifier](http://htmlpurifier.org/).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `strip_tags()`.

```php
$text = '<p>Test paragraph.</p><!-- Comment --> <a href="#fragment">Other text</a>';
echo strip_tags($text);
echo "\n";
    
// Allow <p> and <a>.
echo strip_tags($text, '<p><a>');
```

You can use regular expressions too.

```php
$data = preg_replace('/<script\b[^<]*(?:(?!<\/script>)<[^<]*)*<\/script>/gi', '', $data);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [htmlspecialchars](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) to escape special html characters or [strip_tags](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php) to remove all tags from the string.

Answer (score 0):

A ***URL*** like

```
www.sitename.com/people?job=manager"/><script>alert%2844749%29<%2fscript>
```

will not do anything harmful in and off itself.

A URL like this, *any* value like this, **plainly output into HTML** will of course cause **HTML injection**. Which is why you need to **HTML escape** it:

```
<?php $url = 'www.sitename.com/people?job=manager"/><script>alert%2844749%29<%2fscript>'; ?>

<a href="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($url, ENT_QUOTES); ?>">Click here</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

use urlencode function. Visit https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php for more info.

Answer (score 0):

Instead you can use the following code to directly [filter](https://www.php.net/manual/de/book.filter.php) your input:

```php
$job = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'job', FILTER_SANITIZE_FULL_SPECIAL_CHARS);
```