# Send special characters in the string using POST

Tags: php, html, post

How can i send special characters like  `&` over `POST request`?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php

Comment: Question doesn't make much sense – why would you *not* be able to send & through POST? If you have code that doesn't work, you'll solve your real problem much faster if you show it.

Comment: Thanks. It worked

Comment: please visit this link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17342671/pass-a-percent-sign-in-a-url-and-get-exact-value-of-it-using-php. I hope this link helps you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PHP escape special character in URL param](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11257285/php-escape-special-character-in-url-param)

Answer (score 1):

You can send the `&` character by using the `%26` code.

It would be better practice to use the urlencode php function as mentioned by AbraCadaver above