# Why can't I set a string value in this PHP code?

Tags: php

I visit:

http://www.mydomain.com/test.php?loc=1

This should set $location to be 'VC' and print it out to the screen.

But when I do this, I get a zero '0' instead.

What am I doing wrong, why can't I set a string?

```
<?php
    $loc = $_REQUEST['loc'] ;
if($loc == 1){
$location = 'VC';
echo 'yes';
}
else {
echo "ERROR - Wrong Location code presented";
}   
    echo 'Location: ' + $location;

?>
```

I started with:

```
<?php
    $loc = $_REQUEST['loc'] ;
    echo 'Location: ' + $loc;
?>
```

Where I would visit:

http://www.mydomain.com/test.php?loc=VC

and it would do what I want, but that didn't work.

I must be missing something obvious, but I can't see what. help!

Comment: PHP concatenation is with dots, not +
`echo 'Location: ' . $loc;`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to change it this:

```
<?php
    $loc = $_REQUEST['loc'] ;
    echo 'Location: ' + $loc;
?>
```

to this:

```
<?php
    $loc = $_REQUEST['loc'] ;
    echo 'Location: ' . $loc;
?>
```

PHP's string concatenation operator is the `.` dot instead of a `+` as used in JavaScript, etc.

Comment: Slaps head hard! I knew it was staring me in the face, how stupid of me! What an amateur! LOL

Comment: How do they say? its never too late. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Use `$_GET['loc']` instead of `$_REQUEST['loc']` and concetenate with a `.` instead of a `+` as Mattedgod already stated.

Why `$_GET` instead of `$_REQUEST`?? See: [Among $_REQUEST, $_GET and $_POST which one is the fastest?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1924939/php-request-vs-get-and-post)