# How to run php Delete query in jquery without refreshing page

Tags: php, jquery

I want to delete value from database using PHP.

Using a table row and placed a button like **"Delete"** and I create a function like `onClick='window.location='page.php?action=del&id=1'` and in PHP for delete.

```
if($_REQUEST['action'] == 'del'){
     $req_id = $_REQUEST['id'];
     $del_query = mysql_query("DELETE FROM table WHERE id='$req_id'");
}
```

It's working well but, I don't want to refresh the page. Please tell me how can I do it without page refresh?

Comment: *Never* do operations like DELETE via the query line. *Always* go for *POST*.

Comment: It would take even a script kiddy no more than five seconds to delete your entire database with that setup.

Comment: Apart from SQL injection, using `$_REQUEST` is *bad* as well, `$_REQUEST` contains information from **cookie**, **post** and **get**. It's best to be specific: use `$_POST` or `$_GET`, depending on what you're expecting; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1924939/php-request-vs-get-and-post

Answer (score 1):

```
<button id='delete'>Click Me To Delete</button>

 $('#delete').on('click',function(){

 $.ajax({
    type:'POST',
    url:'page.php',
    data:'action=del&id=1',
    success:function(result){
              //Deleted  
    }

  });

 });
```

Comment: Doesn't one need to put ' or " when passing string as data?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="if('Are you sure you want to delete?'){delData(this,1);}">delete</a>

<script type="text/javascript">
function delData(control,id){
  $.ajax({type:'POST', url:'page.php?action=del&id='+id, success:function(result){
   //alert('deleted');
     $(control).parents('table').eq(0).remove();
   }
  });
}
<script>
```

**NOTE:**

1. You will need to add jQuery file for this.
2. This process is called ajax. Google it.
3. Then try to pass the data in post parameter rather than in query string.

**Update:** Note that now the 'this' is passed as a reference of this control to the method delData.

Comment: What is the advantage of POST over GET?

Comment: What should I place on delete button where currently I placed this:
onClick='window.location='page.php?action=del&id=1'

Comment: @jantimon If you ask what is the advantage of POST over GET HERE? Then that's a valid question, I just wanted to mention an approach so that at least in non-ajax requests, it wont be showing in the address bar itself. In ajax how can to send json data as a request parameter by the way?

Comment: @user2140704 See the updated answer, it is just for the reference as I am passing hard coded 1 as id. You can modify it according to your needs.

Comment: Search-engine indexing machines use 'GET' to crawl your website. Imagine Google indexing your website and following these links; `page.php?action=del&id=1`, `page.php?action=del&id=2`. `POST` is for *sending (hence 'post') data* and should be used to modify data. `GET` is to *retrieve (hence 'get') data*.

Comment: Its working for me but when I click on delete its showing a dialogue box called deleted and then I press ok on that dialogue value still there and when i refresh my page then its removed.. I want to remove and hide it immediately on clicking delete button..

Comment: Yeah.. you can see an `alert('deleted');` written inside success function. That is the place where you need to do something. Edit your question and post full relevant code, or do it your self. You just have to remove the related div. A better approach would be to return partial view from server if you are using php but anyways. Something like `$(control).parent('div').remove();` should remove it. See the updated answer.

Comment: I use $(control).parent('table').remove(); but its not working still same when I refresh then it is going to hide.. :( also remember i want to use if(confirm('Do you really want to remove it ?')) before deleting it.. Thanks

Comment: Here is full code:
`<a style="border:0px; cursor:pointer;" onclick="delData(<?php echo $id; ?>)" title="Delete"><img src="images/delete.gif" /></a>`

AND
`
function delData(id){
$.ajax({type:'POST', url:'manage_reports.php?action=del&id='+id, success:function(result){alert('deleted');}});
$(control).parent('table').remove();
}`

Comment: See the updated code. You have to use `$(control).parents('table').eq(0).remove();` and also notice the implemented confirm box there.

Comment: I replaced the code with this: $(control).parents('table').eq(0).remove(); but still not working..

Comment: ok.. then google a bit about how to remove any html element using jquery as no one can assume what is there in your html markup so can't exactly tell you what to remove or what to write