# How to get variable in url

Tags: php, query-string

I am having problem in getting variable from one PHP page to another PHP page. The problem is I can't get the variable. I use this code to move to another page :

```
$updateGoTo = "closeticketscs.php";
if (isset($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])) {
    $updateGoTo .= (strpos($updateGoTo, '?')) ? "&" : "?";
    $updateGoTo .= $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
}
```

and I've tried code below to get the variable :

```
$updateGoTo = "closeticketscs.php?id=echo $row_searchreslt['ID'];";
if (isset($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])) {
    $updateGoTo .= (strpos($updateGoTo, '?')) ? "&" : "?";
    $updateGoTo .= $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
}
```

However, this doesn't work. Any help will be appreciated. Here is the right code :

```
$updateGoTo = "closeticketscs.php?id=".$_POST['ID_Pelanggan'];
  if (isset($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])) 
  {
    $updateGoTo .= ((strpos($updateGoTo, '?') > -1) ? "&" : "?" ).
    $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
  }
```

header(sprintf("Location: %s", $updateGoTo));

Comment: Take a look at GET: [GET FROM PHP.NET](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your second code, i think you have a mistake.
you dont need to echo a php variable file when you declare a variable to another variable.

change

```
  $updateGoTo = "closeticketscs.php?id=echo $row_searchreslt['ID'];";
```

to

```
  $updateGoTo = "closeticketscs.php?id=".$row_searchreslt['ID'];
```

and if you want to get a variable from page to another page, just use $_GET. example,

in index.php

```
 <?php
 $updateGoTo = "closeticketscs.php?id=".$row_searchreslt['ID'];
 echo '<a href="'.$updateGoTo.'">Go Here</a>';
 ?>
```

and in closeticketscs.php

```
 <?php
 $new_variable = $_GET['id'];
 //now you get the variable 'id' from the url closeticketscs.php?id=value
 ?>
```

if use form :

```
 <form method="get" action="closeticketscs.php">
 <input type="text" name="id" value="123" >
 <input type="submit" value="Click Here" name="click">
 </form>
```

Comment: Ive tried your suggestion, but still won't work. When I echo the $new_variable it doesn't appear :(

Comment: is the $row_searchreslt['ID'] variable has been declared? check your url before you click the link, is closeticketscs.php?id=somevalue or just closeticketscs.php?id=

Comment: yes haha. klo cuma closeticketscs.php?id= , berarti variabel $row_searchreslt['ID'] nya kosong. variabel $_GET['id'] keisi kalo di link nya closeticketscs.php?id=adavaluenya

Comment: Nah, iya ngga keisi. sebenernya itu ID bisa ngga ya kalo ambil dari name, soalnya id nya itu kecetak gini : <input type="hidden" name="ID">

Comment: coba kirim scriptnya ke email gw, soalnya gw masih belum ngerti apa yang harus dikirim. bisa sih pake input juga, tapi pakenya form

Comment: sorry td gw udah balik hehe dy_qie21@yahoo.com. klo pake form, link nya berupa tombol. contoh nya liat jwban yang gw edit

Comment: glad to hear that. keep coding :D

Answer (score 3):

Did you try $_GET?

```
if (isset($_GET['id']) {
    $id = $_GET['id']
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (isset($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])) {
   $updateGoTo .= ( (strpos($updateGoTo, '?') > -1) ? "&" : "?" ) . $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
}
```

If you want to check for question mark with strpos you must use > -1  :)
And you can .= in 1 line no need to make it on 2

Comment: So, I have to use >-1 to make it work (link to another page)?

Answer (score 0):

//If your link is closeticketscs.php?id=12345

```
if (isset($_REQUEST['id']){
   $id= $_REQUEST['id'];
   echo $id;
}
```

[Among $_REQUEST, $_GET and $_POST which one is the fastest?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1924939/php-request-vs-get-and-post) this is more about request get and post.