# PHP and SQL Injection

Tags: php, sql, security, code-injection

I have this piece of PHP, I just wanna make sure it's safe from SQL injection and security vulnerabilities:

```
<?php
require_once "./source/includes/data.php";
header('Content-type: application/json');
$request = mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['email_address']);

$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM mmh_user_info WHERE email_address ='$request'");
$result = mysql_num_rows($query);
if ($result == 0){
$valid = 'true';}
else{
$valid = 'false';
}
echo $valid;
?>
```

I'm still a php newbie, any enhancements or edits would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Pretty safe from injection, but if you're writing new code, why not go with either `PDO`'s or `mysqli`'s prepared statments? Safe as can be..

Comment: `$email_address` in your WHERE clause likely should be `$request`. Besides that, safe.

Comment: Can you suggest an edit on this code? Or suggest a tutorial that explains how to do that in mysqli prepared statments? Thanks for your advice!

Comment: We would need to see how you output the data and how you inserted it, since this `could` still be vulnerable to XSS in certain cases.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest you make use of PDO which is becoming a standard in PHP5:

```
$sth = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM mmh_user_info WHERE email_address = ?");
$sth->execute(array($_REQUEST['email_address']));
$red = $sth->fetchAll();
```

Comment: An additional `isset` check is required here

Comment: Shouldn't there be an `array()` inside `execute()` @zerkms

Comment: @php NoOb: that's too, but it's not my answer :-)

Comment: mysqli extension also supports prepared statements.

Comment: I'm using this with jQuery validate 'remote'. I need the result to be true or false, can this be done with PDO ?

Answer (score 1):

I would use $_POST instead of $_REQUEST for the points noted in [this great answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1924958/938236) by the user `Pascal MARTIN`:

> [`$_REQUEST`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.request.php), by default, contains the contents of `$_GET`, `$_POST` and `$_COOKIE`.
>
> But it's only a default, which depends on [`variables_order`](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.variables-order) ; and not sure you want to work with cookies.
>
> If I had to choose, I would probably not use `$_REQUEST`, and I would choose `$_GET` or `$_POST` -- **depending on what my application should do** *(i.e. one or the other, but not both)* : generally speaking :
>
> - You should use `$_GET` when someone is requesting data **from** your application.
> - And you should use `$_POST` when someone is pushing *(inserting or updating ; or deleting)* data **to** your application.
>
> Either way, there will not be much of a difference about performances : the difference will be negligible, compared to what the rest of your script will do.