# is $_REQUEST unsafe to use instead of $_POST or $_GET?

Tags: php, post, get, request

can i use `$_REQUEST` to get values of form instead of `$_GET` or `$_POST`?

if i use $_REQUEST always is it unsafe or has any differents?

thank you to reply

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$_REQUEST` contains `$_GET` and `$_POST` and it's not inherently less secure. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1924939/php-request-vs-get-and-post).

Answer (score 0):

request have both get and post - no big difference in security .

unsafe is when you directly use that $_request value in sql .

do some checking and assign to variable and use it sql