# How would I retrieve the data on a different page?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I'm Sending this Video Blob to the uploadVideo.php file how would i retrieve it on the uploadvideo.php page?

```
function postVideoToServer(videoblob) {
        var data = {};
        data.video = videoblob;
        data.metadata = 'test metadata';
        data.action = "upload_video";
        jQuery.post("http://mysite.com/uploadvideo.php", data, onUploadSuccess);
    }
```

**More Details**

```
function postVideoToServer(videoblob) {
    var data = {};
    data.video = videoblob;
    data.metadata = 'test metadata';
    data.action = "upload_video";
    jQuery.post("http://mysite.com/uploadvideo.php", data, onUploadSuccess);
}
```

And On the uploadvideo.php i have this:

```
    <?php
    require("connect.php");

    $video = $_POST["video"];
    $up = mysql_query("INSERT INTO video VALUES ('$video')");
    ?>
```

But it still does not seem to work? I Think i am doing something wrong?

Comment: `$_POST['video']`, `$_POST['metadata']`, `$_POST['action']` ?

Comment: try `$video = addslashes($_POST["video"]);`, as special characters like `'` can be in `$video`

Answer (score 2):

```
$video = $_POST['video'];
$metadata = $_POST['metadata'];
$action = $_POST['action'];
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use either `$_REQUEST["key"]`

```
$video = $_REQUEST["video"];
$metadata = $_REQUEST["metadata"]; //test metadata
$action = $_REQUEST["action"]; //upload_video
```

or `$_POST["key"]`

```
$video = $_POST["video"];
$metadata = $_POST["metadata"]; //test metadata
$action = $_POST["action"]; //upload_video
```

to retrieve the data sent to the PHP script.

To read a little bit more about different data retrieval techniques and their comparison in PHP refer [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1924958/1618713).

Comment: I Put this into the uploadvideo.php but it does not seen to work maybe its the script for the getusermedia?                               require("connect.php");
$video = $_POST["video"];
$up = mysql_query("INSERT INTO video VALUES ('$video')");

Answer (score 0):

uploadvideo.php:

```
$video = $_POST["video"];
$metadata = $_POST["metadata"]; //test metadata
$action = $_POST["action"]; //upload_video
...
```

now you can do whatever you want with these.

Comment: Hi, I Added A bit more details still does's not seem to work?