# Why submit form without refreshing not add database values?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, form-submit, page-refresh

I have the following form and this script to connect with the class operation.php it doesn't refresh and neither add the data into database.

I have no idea why it's not adding to the database

## Form

```
<form id="formulario" method="POST">
    <textarea id="valor" name="valor"></textarea>
    <input type="hidden" id="idproyecto" name="idproyecto" value="<?php echo $hist->idproyecto;?>"/>
    <input type="hidden" id="idsprint" name="idsprint" value="<?php echo $hist->idsprint;?>"/>
    <input type="hidden" id="idhistoria" name="idhistoria" value="<?php echo $hist->idhistoria;?>"/>
    <input type="hidden" id="idusuario" name="idusuario" value="<?php echo $user->idusuario;?>"/>
    <input  id="Confirmar"  class="button" name="operacion" type="submit" value="Confirmar" />
    <span class="advertencia" style="display:none"> Please Enter Valid Data</span>
    <span class="completado" style="display:none"> Registration Successfully</span>
</form>
```

## Script

```
$(function() {
    $(".button").click(function() {
        var idproyecto = $("#idproyecto").val();
        var idsprint = $("#idsprint").val();
        var idhistoria = $("#idhistoria").val();
        var idusuario = $("#idusuario").val();
        var valor = $("#valor").val();
        var dataString = 'idproyecto='+ idproyecto + '&idsprint=' + idsprint + '&idhistoria=' + idhistoria + '&idusuario=' + idusuario + '&valor=' + valor;
         alert(dataString);
        if(valor=='')
        {
            $('.completado').fadeOut(200).hide();
            $('.advertencia').fadeOut(200).show();
        }else{
            $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "../admin/poker/operacion_poker.php",
            data: dataString,
            success: function(){
                $('.completado').fadeIn(200).show();
                $('.advertencia').fadeOut(200).hide();}
            });
        }
        return false;
    });
});
```

And i have this class operation_poker.php to receive the values and add to database

## PHP

```html
include_once('../../clases/poker.php');
$operacion=$_REQUEST['operacion'];
$temporal_poker=new poker(0,$_REQUEST['idproyecto'],$_REQUEST['idsprint'],$_REQUEST['idhistoria'],$_REQUEST['idusuario'],$_REQUEST['valor'],0);
switch($operacion)
{
    case 'Confirmar':
        $temporal_poker->inserta_poker();
        break;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using:

```
$(function() {
    $(".button").click(function() {,
```

use this:

```
$(function() {
    $("#formulario").submit(function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
```

Since your button is a submit type, you have to intercept form's `submit` event for this to work correctly. Also note you have to prevent the normal submit behavior from occurring, so you also have to add the line `event.preventDefault();`.

And Matthew is right, you should get your data from `$_POST`, not `$_REQUEST`.

Answer (score 1):

You are sending the data via $_POST, try accessing the values from $_POST instead of $_REQUEST. Normally $_REQUEST would have the data in $_POST, but since you are getting information at runtime, PHP may not be updating the $_REQUEST variable.

Here is a [great post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1924939/php-request-vs-get-and-post) about `variables_order` and the best uses for $_REQUEST over $_GET, $_POST and $_COOKIE.