# Display search term in URL php

Tags: php

All I want is to display my search term in the url. Somehow I am not able to get it.

```
<?php $string = stripcslashes(isset($_GET['string']));?>

<form action="index.php?string=<?php echo $string;?>" method="post">
    <input name="string" type="text" class="inputbox" id="String" 
    value="<?php echo stripcslashes(isset($_REQUEST["string"])); ?>" 
    size="40" style="width:250px"/>
</form>
```

Also there is always a `1` displaying in my search field after I make a search. I am sure that is what is messing it up.

Comment: "echo"ing isset doesn't make sense?

Comment: `isset($_REQUEST["string"])` will return true, or 1. I think you want `value="<?php echo stripcslashes(isset($_REQUEST["string"])?$_REQUEST["string"]:''); ?>

Comment: all i had to do was to change from post to get

Answer (score 2):

The code `<?php $string = stripcslashes(isset($_GET['string']));?>` is going to return you either a 1 or 0.

You have to do like this..

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['string']))
{
$string = stripcslashes($_GET['string']);
}
?>
<form action="index.php?string=<?php echo $string;?>" method="post"><input name="string" type="text" class="inputbox" id="String" value="<?php echo $string; ?>" size="40" style="width:250px"/></form>
```

Comment: Additionally, you shouldn't be using $_REQUEST and here's why: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1924939/php-request-vs-get-and-post

Comment: all i had to do was change from post to get

Answer (score 1):

[`isset()`](http://php.net/isset) function returns a boolean value, not the value of the variable itself.

From the manual page:

> **bool** isset ( mixed $var [, mixed $... ] )

If you're trying to check if the variable `$_GET['string']` is defined and then set its value equal to `stripcslashes($_GET['string'])`, then you can do it as follows, using a ternary statement:

```
$string = (isset($_GET['string'])) ? stripcslashes($_GET['string']) : '';
```

Comment: all i had to do was change from post to get

Comment: @user3077454: Ah! I didn't notice the form `method`. Of course, it wouldn't work with `POST`. However, you'd have noticed this easily if you had indented your code properly. Anyway, I'm glad you solved the issue :)

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php $string = (isset($_GET['string']))?stripcslashes($_GET['string']):'';?>
```

Comment: all i had to do was change from post to get