# Save text from URL

Tags: php, url, text, save

I found this code. He saves a text file on the server
I want to change it instead to have a textBox and button. 
Have the possibility to compose the URL 
Example:
www.example.com/index.php?writeText=text 
What needs to change in this code to do this?

```
<html>
<body>
    <form name="form" method="post">
        <input type="text" name="text_box" size="50"/>
        <input type="submit" id="search-submit" value="submit" />
    </form>
</body>
```

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['text_box'])) { //only do file operations when appropriate
        $a = $_POST['text_box'];
        $myFile = "t.txt";
        $fh = fopen($myFile, 'w') or die("can't open file");
        fwrite($fh, $a);
        fclose($fh);
    }
?>
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you clear up what you're asking?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use GET instead of POST.

```
<?php
    if(isset($_GET['writeText'])) { //only do file operations when appropriate
        $a = $_GET['writeText'];
        $myFile = "t.txt";
        $fh = fopen($myFile, 'w') or die("can't open file");
        fwrite($fh, $a);
        fclose($fh);
    }
?>
```

Comment: If you were to use $_REQUEST instead of $_GET, the same code could work with a get and a post. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1924939/php-request-vs-get-and-post) stackoverflow answer for more info.