# Not able to pass parameter to jquery load url

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

My code is as follows

```
$(document).ready(function(){

      var bed = $( "input[name=bed]:checked" ).val();
      var bud = $( "input[name=bud]:checked" ).val();
      var loc = $("#autocomplete").val();

      $("#search_list").load('main_frame2.php?bed='+bed+'&bud='+bud+'&loc1='+loc);
    });
```

In `main_frame2.php`

```
<?
    session_start();

    echo $loc = $_GET['loc1']   ;
    echo $bed = $_REQUEST['bed']    ;
    echo $bud = $_REQUEST['bud']    ;

?>
```

I am getting the values of bed and bud. But m not getting for loc.
But if i use alert inside jquery function m getting loc name which is not passing to `main_frame2.php`

Comment: use $_GET['loc1'] instead of $_POST['loc1']

Comment: You have to URL-encode each parameter value if you build GET query manually.

Answer (score 1):

`load` sends a GET request, yet your PHP is looking in the `$_POST` for the `loc1` value. Try using `$_REQUEST` or better yet, `$_GET` to retrieve your querystring values.

```
<?
    session_start();
    echo $loc = $_GET['loc1'];
    echo $bed = $_GET['bed'];
    echo $bud = $_GET['bud'];
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

jQuery load does a `GET`. So instead of getting `$loc` with `$_POST['loc1'];`, try `$_GET['loc1'];`

Answer (score 1):

Use `$_GET` instead of `$_POST`, your are not posting but getting the data.

Explanation of jQuery

> The POST method is used if data is provided as an object; otherwise,
>   GET is assumed.

Answer (score 1):

Replace first line of code in PHP file with

> echo $loc = $_GET['loc1'];

Answer (score 1):

If you read the documentation, it says

> .load( url [, data ] [, complete ] )

[**Documentation**](http://api.jquery.com/load/)

It means you can pass data in second arguement in JSON format. Also, .load internally uses GET method so modify your PHP Code accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
      var bed = $( "input[name=bed]:checked" ).val();
      var bud = $( "input[name=bud]:checked" ).val();
      var loc = $("#autocomplete").val();

      $("#search_list").load('main_frame2.php', {bed: bed, bud: bud: loc: loc}, function(){
           console.log('PHP Loaded');
      });
});
```

Then on your PHP:

```
<?
    session_start();

    echo $loc = $_GET['loc']  ; <<== since you are getting data from URL
    echo $bed = $_REQUEST['bed']; <<== you can also use $_GET['bed']
    echo $bud = $_REQUEST['bud']; <<== you can also use $_GET['bud']

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You're passing the variables in the URL. This implies you're making a `GET` request to *main_frame2.php*.

From [the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.request.php) `$_REQUEST` returns **all** the HTTP Request variables :

> An associative array that by default contains the contents of `$_GET`, `$_POST` and `$_COOKIE`

So either you access all your variables as `$_REQUEST['foo']` or `$_GET['foo']`.

A [relevant post on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1924958/1083314) that might clarify things further. Hope it gets you started in the right direction.