# Parsing values in Get request with form options

Tags: html, forms, get

Short question how do I parse values from options in a form ?

I have this form group

```
<div class="form-group form-group-lg form-group-select-plus">
<label>Rooms</label>
<div class="btn-group btn-group-select-num" data-toggle="buttons">
  <label class="btn btn-primary active    ">
    <input type="radio" name="rooms" value="1"/>1</label>
  <label class="btn btn-primary">
    <input type="radio" name="rooms" value="2"/>2</label>
  <label class="btn btn-primary">
    <input type="radio" name="rooms" value="3"/>3</label>
  <label class="btn btn-primary">
    <input type="radio" name="options" />3+</label>
</div>
<select class="form-control hidden">
    <option name="rooms" value="1">1</option>
    <option name="rooms" value="2">2</option>
    <option name="rooms" value="3">3</option>
    <option name="rooms" value="4" selected="selected">4</option>
    <option name="rooms" value="5">5</option>
    <option name="rooms" value="6">6</option>
    <option name="rooms" value="7">7</option>
    <option name="rooms" value="8">8</option>
    <option name="rooms" value="9">9</option>
    <option name="rooms" value="10">10</option>
    <option name="rooms" value="11">11</option>
    <option name="rooms" value="12">12</option>
    <option name="rooms" value="13">13</option>
    <option name="rooms" value="14">14</option>
</select>
</div>
```

I can submit the values in the input fields without a problem but how do I parse the once in the option fields. Assuming the name I want to parse is "rooms"

I'm using PHP to process the form data.

Comment: Parse in _what_? Which language are you using to process the form data? PHP? JavaScript?

Comment: PHP $_GET , Sorry for bad explanation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<select>`'s hold the name attribute, not the `<option>`'s

```
<select class="form-control hidden" name="rooms">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4" selected="selected">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
    <option value="6">6</option>
    <option value="7">7</option>
    <option value="8">8</option>
    <option value="9">9</option>
    <option value="10">10</option>
    <option value="11">11</option>
    <option value="12">12</option>
    <option value="13">13</option>
    <option value="14">14</option>
</select>
```

Then your handler will take the value chosen from your form's select.

Assuming a POST method:

```
$rooms = $_POST['rooms'];
```

Assuming a GET method:

```
$rooms = $_GET['rooms'];
```

- However, you have radio buttons with the same name attribute. You will need to set each element as a unique name if you intend on using all of those together with the select.

Answer (score 0):

You can access the values of `rooms` by using `$_GET['rooms']` *if* the form is submitted using `get`. Else there still is `$_POST` or if you are unsure, try `var_dump`ing `$_REQUEST`.

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/1924958/151509 for more on that.