# How to retrieve values from datepicker in a datepicker input field (using PHP MySQL)?

Tags: php, mysql, jquery-ui, datepicker

I have this form to update a record using PHP MySQL. I want to retrieve the value of the date column in a datepicker field. Is that possible? I try using `$_REQUEST['date']`, but the result is empty.
This is my  form code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">             
    $(function(){
        $('#date_4').datepicker({
            dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'
        }); 
    });     
</script>

<form enctype="multipart/form-data" id="fm" method="post" novalidate>
    <div class="fitem">
        <label>No:</label>
        <input name="id" id="id" class="easyui-validatebox" size="50" required> 
    </div>
    <div class="fitem">
        <label>Date:</label>
        <input id="date_4" name="date_3" class="easyui-validatebox" size="50">          
    </div>
    <div class="fitem">
        <label>From:</label>
        <input id="from" name="from" class="easyui-validatebox" size="50" required>
    </div>
    <div class="fitem">
        <label>Hal:</label>
        <textarea name="hal" class="easyui-validatebox" cols="48" rows="5" required></textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="fitem">
        <label>attachment:</label>
        <input type="hidden" name="max_file_size" value="20000" />
        <input name="userfile" type="file" />
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: please share your form code...

Comment: please share your html code!

Comment: Your `$_REQUEST['date']` is empty because you don't have a form element with `name="date"`. You have a `name="date_3"`.

Comment: my bad i mean $_REQUEST['date_3']

Answer (score 0):

You are using method="post" on your form, hence it'd be more correct to grab it from $_POST['date_3']. See the code below (sorry for the length, thought it'd be better to show the full thing)

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta ncharset="utf-8"/>  
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">      
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

    <?php   
        if(isset($_POST['date_3'])){
            echo $_POST['date_3'];
        }
    ?>

    <form enctype="multipart/form-data" id="fm" method="post" novalidate>
        <div class="fitem">
            <label>No:</label>
            <input name="id" id="id" class="easyui-validatebox" size="50" required> 
        </div>
        <div class="fitem">
            <label>Date:</label>
            <input id="date_4" name="date_3" class="easyui-validatebox" size="50">          
        </div>
        <div class="fitem">
            <label>From:</label>
            <input id="from" name="from" class="easyui-validatebox" size="50" required>
        </div>
        <div class="fitem">
            <label>Hal:</label>
            <textarea name="hal" class="easyui-validatebox" cols="48" rows="5" required></textarea>
        </div>
        <div class="fitem">
            <label>attachment:</label>
            <input type="hidden" name="max_file_size" value="20000" />
            <input name="userfile" type="file" />
        </div>
        <input type="submit" value="Go!">
    </form>

    <script type="text/javascript">             
        $(function(){
            $('#date_4').datepicker({
                dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'
            }); 
        });     
    </script>

</body>    
</html>
```

Either way, it works fine for $_REQUEST too, since $REQUEST holds $_GET, $_POST and $_COOKIE (see this post about [$_REQUEST vs $_GET and $_POST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1924939/request-vs-get-and-post)) You can replace the PHP code above with the following and it will still print your date, if you select one, once you submit it:

```
<?php   
if(isset($_REQUEST['date_3'])){
    echo $_REQUEST['date_3'];
}
?>
```