# what $_REQUEST will return when same values sent by GET and POST?

Tags: php, forms, post, get

I am trying to make a form in `PHP`, I used user ID to show data in form by GET, but after submitting form by POST i stored user ID in a hidden field..

While trying this i just became confused with `GET`, `POST` and `REQUEST`.

See this situation

```
<form action="script.php?id=777" method="post">
     ID: <input type="text" name="id" />
     <input type="submit" value="Send" />
</form>
```

Let's suppose i enter '888' in text field 
when this form will be submitted, what value `$_REQUEST['id'];` should provide?

It will be same in all `php versions`?

What will happen if I left text field blank?

and what will happen if I change action as `action="script.php?id="`?

Comment: Are you not able to check this at your end. how much time it will take?

Comment: It's working unexpected some times.. I just wanted be sure that is there any rule for it. So that i can rely on it before using it in project.

Comment: The best thing is don't use `$_REQUEST`. why - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2142497/whats-wrong-with-using-request

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The actual order is determined in the "request_order" setting in the PHP.ini file

```
; This directive determines which super global data (G,P,C,E & S) should
; be registered into the super global array REQUEST. If so, it also determines
; the order in which that data is registered. The values for this directive are
; specified in the same manner as the variables_order directive, EXCEPT one.
; Leaving this value empty will cause PHP to use the value set in the
; variables_order directive. It does not mean it will leave the super globals
; array REQUEST empty.
; Default Value: None
; Development Value: "GP"
; Production Value: "GP"
; http://php.net/request-order
request_order = "GP"
```

Usually the default setting is Get then Post. In this case you supply the id parameter as get AND as a post parameter. This means the $_REQUEST is populated with the $_GET first, then $_POST. Meaning $_REQUEST will reflect $_POST.

Comment: Thnx @Ronald.. that's why it was working differently in different systems, got technique behind it. thnx.

Answer (score 3):

**01**

If form is in `post` method

```
<form action="script.php" method="post">
     ID: <input type="text" name="id" />
     <input type="submit" value="Send" />
</form>
```

In `script.php`, you can get data by using

```
$id = $_POST['id'];//works
$id = $_REQUEST['id'];//works
$id = $_GET['id'];//Failed
```

**02**

If form is in `get` method

```
<form action="script.php" method="get">
     ID: <input type="text" name="id" />
     <input type="submit" value="Send" />
</form>
```

In `script.php`, you can get data by using

```
$id = $_GET['id'];//works
$id = $_REQUEST['id'];//works
$id = $_POST['id'];//Failed
```

You can refer [$_REQUEST vs $_GET and $_POST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1924939/request-vs-get-and-post) and [What's wrong with using $_REQUEST[]?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2142497/whats-wrong-with-using-request)

Comment: Thnx, but i just wanted to know that if `'?id=1'` is in url and `id = 2` is sent by POST then `$_REQUEST[''id] = ?`.

Comment: Ok, means i can't rely that always it will give `=1`, because i tried sometimes it give `=2`..