# How to get string from PHP server to Android?

Tags: php, android, server, postdata

I create the application to send a text to the server and check `if(text != null)` return new text values.

My code to do this like:

In PHP Server:

```
$text = $_POST["text1"];
if($text != null){
    echo "Contact1-----".$text."-----10h49 25/03/2016 at New York city";
} else{
    echo "";
}
```

Before, I save a file on the server and write all data to this file.
At this time, I want it to return back to android data, don't need to save to file.
And in Android code is:

```
final String scripturlstring = "http://www.anyexample.com/main.php";

AddContactActivity contact;
public void sendToServer(final String text){
    contact = new AddContactActivity();
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {

                String textparam = "text1=" + URLEncoder.encode(text, "UTF-8");

                URL scripturl = new URL(scripturlstring);
                HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) scripturl.openConnection();
                connection.setDoOutput(true);
                connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
                connection.setFixedLengthStreamingMode(textparam.getBytes().length);
                contentWriter.write(textparam);
                contentWriter.flush();
                contentWriter.close();

                InputStream answerInputStream = connection.getInputStream();
                final String answer = getTextFromInputStream(answerInputStream);

                if(answer!="") {
                    String[] contactInfo = answer.split("-----");

                    contact.insertContact(contactInfo[0], contactInfo[1], contactInfo[2], "", "");
                }
                answerInputStream.close();
                connection.disconnect();


            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }).start();

}



public String getTextFromInputStream(InputStream is) {
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

    String currentLine;
    try {
        while ((currentLine = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            stringBuilder.append(currentLine);
            stringBuilder.append("\n");
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return stringBuilder.toString().trim();
}
```

I don't know why `answer` is `null`.

I think it must return the data like:

`Contact1      $text         10h49 25/03/2016 at New York city`

Comment: what happens if you open anyexample.com/main.php?text1=asd in the browser?

Comment: @Eduard7 It doesn't show anything. Do you think occurs in PHP file?

Comment: try to change $_POST["text1"] to $_GET["text1"]

Comment: I tried with `$GET["text1"] and `$_REQUEST['text1'] but I don't receive values from server.

Comment: not $GET but $_GET. don't use $_REQUEST: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1924939/among-request-get-and-post-which-one-is-the-fastest

Comment: @Eduard7 yes, I using `$_GET` but it not working for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Leave the Android part and debug your PHP code first. You're not posting the data, so this is definitely wrong:

```
$text = $_POST["text1"];
```

Use $_GET["text1"] instead:

```
$text = $_GET["text1"];
```

You can use $_REQUEST though, but IMO it's a bad practice, as it merges down the $_GET, $_POST and $_COOKIE variables.

Comment: Thanks to @Eduard7, I using class `sendToServer(final String text)` posting a line and want to receive a new string from PHP server through `echo` new string values.

After having received a new line, my application will continue another process.

Answer (score 1):

Replace

`$text = $_POST["text1"];`
with

```
$text = $_REQUEST['text1'];
```

Comment: Thanks @Dhavalkumar Solanki: I tried your change. In Android client, I don't receive any values from server PHP. I think a problem in `getTextFromInputStream`class because before this class get values in a file. Current, I get values direct from `echo` in PHP server.

Comment: Hi ioewi some time log should not work for Http method so if you able to debug then debug and check response, i have got same issue before some time, Log should not work but when i set in textview it work perfect

Comment: thank you very much. I don't use `TextView` because many problems. Simple, I want to check `text` in server and server responds with `echo` new string `text`. I receive this line and at to my application to continues process.

Answer (score 0):

set `connection.setDoInput(true);`