# Trimming blank values from a GET statement

Tags: html, forms, get

I'm submitting a large form through the GET method (so the results can easily be saved and shared). Inputs in the form are allowed to be blank. Is there a way to have the GET statement link not include blank results?

So if I had three items, and item 1 and item 3 have values, it would look like this

```
website.com?item1=value&item3=value
```

Instead of

```
website.com?item1=value&item2=&item3=value
```

Comment: [Among $_REQUEST, $_GET and $_POST which one is the fastest?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1924939/among-request-get-and-post-which-one-is-the-fastest)
If you are using $_GET to submit form (insert/delete/update) it is not "right" way, use preferably $_POST method.
Note that there is no limit on the number of FORM elements you can pass via POST, but only on the aggregate size of all name/value pairs. **While GET is limited to as low as 1024 characters**, POST data is limited to 2 MB (but you can increase it with php.ini) on IIS 4.0, and 128 KB on IIS 5.0

Comment: Ok... but this doesn't answer the question. And as I said POST wouldn't be beneficial in my circumstance.

Comment: Then, write JS. When input is null change it to disabled input.