# Passing PHP URL variables leads to Page Not Found

Tags: php, html

I have an image that is supposed to redirect to another page when it's clicked. It also "sends" two variables to the page, `s` and `n`.

```
echo "<a href='../?change-preference&s=up&n=".$element."'> 
         <img src='..media/images/sort-up.png'>
      </a>";
```

On the `change-preference` page I get the two variables like so:

```
$s=$_REQUEST['s'];
$n=$_REQUEST['n'];
```

My problem is that I get a "Page Not Found" error.

Also, if I try to directly access the page it works, but only if I type this:

`www.example.com/preference/change-preference`

and not if I try it with :

`www.example.com/preference/change-preference&s=up&n=999`

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: htaccess rewrite issue?

Comment: Consider using $_GET https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1924939/among-request-get-and-post-which-one-is-the-fastest#1924958

Comment: @arkascha I tried that but when it redirects there is a `/` before the variables. `..eference/?s=up&n=999`.

Comment: There is a difference between the two URL formats you are goving in your question. Note the difference _before_ "change-preference": `../?change-preference&s=up&n=999` != `preference/change-preference&s=up&n=999`...

Answer (score 2):

You should use:

```
www.example.com/preference/change-preference?s=up&n=999
```

Comment: I tried to do that but the url becomes `www.example.com/preference/change-preference/?s=up&n=999` and it's againa Page not found.

Comment: Thought so too, but look at the format of the URL used in the php code snippet, opposed to the format in the description below.

Comment: @StamatiaCh Use you framework i.e. ZendFramework? Than check: www.example.com/preference/change-preference/s/up/n/999

Answer (score 1):

The `?` is being used in the incorrect place when you are building your link.

You need to build your link as follows:

```
$element = 900;
echo "<a href='../change-preference?s=up&n=" . $element ."'><img src='..media/images/sort-up.png'></a>";
```

This will give you:

```
www.example.com/preference/change-preference?s=up&n=900
```

And in the following link from your question the `?` is missing, which will not work:

```
www.example.com/preference/change-preference&s=up&n=999
```

Answer (score 0):

First you are using `?` in the incorrect place as Daniel_ZA pointed out or you have typed incorrectly on your question the url that actually works. For this answer I will assume that it is the first case.

Second, do you have a php file named "change-preferences" without the .php extension? It is being parsed via php. I think probably not. So you should have a folder named change-preferences then and a file named index.php inside it right?

Well, that's the reason `change-preference?s=up&n=900` redirects to `change-preference\?s=up&n=900`. Because you are accessing the index file for that address and not directly a file. It should work fine however.

If it still return a 404 (Page not Found) error then it's probably something that you haven't include in your question that isn't well configured or is having a bad behavior. Please try a simpler setup (create a new folder with only the minimal necessary to execute the url) or provide more information on your question.

Answer (score 0):

Well.. I didn't mention that I am working with Wordpress because I thought this was 100% PHP question. It appears that "s" is a reserved term in Wordpress causing a 404 error. Changing the "s" fixed the problem. I am living this answer here in case that some one else working on Wordpress finds him/her self in the same position. Al of the [reserved terms](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_taxonomy#Reserved_Terms).