# Storing post content to variable

Tags: php, sql, httprequest

*http request code*

```
POST /parse.php HTTP/1.1
Host: mysite.com
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Length: 26
Content-Type: application/x-www-urlencoded

lt=12.123123&ln=123.123123
```

*php code*

```
//connect to database codes here
$database = "update name_tbl set lat='".$_GET['lt']."', lng='".$_GET['ln']."' where id=1";
mysqli_query($conn, $database)
```

So my problem I think is in the php part when I enter mysite.com/parse.php?lt=12.123123&ln=123.123123 to test if it's working and it does but when I the http request code on *HttpRequest* it but the send value is both 0.000000.

Comment: if you're issuing a post request, your variables will be in `$_POST`, not `$_GET`. also, if a user sets `lt` to `'; drop table name_tbl;--`, something unintended might happen, watch for that.

Comment: Read it, use it, fast! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php

Comment: @AbraCadaver Dont worry the data above is just for testing, and thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you aren't sure whether the request has come to you via a `GET` or a `POST` method, you could try something like this

```
$lt = isset($_GET['lt']) ? $_GET['lt'] : (isset($_POST['lt']) ? $_POST['lt'] : null);
$ln = isset($_GET['ln']) ? $_GET['ln'] : (isset($_POST['ln']) ? $_POST['ln'] : null);
```

There might be another option called `$_REQUEST` which encompasses both `$_GET` and `$_POST` but has it own quirks too. Please have a read on the following link to get a better idea:

[Among $_REQUEST, $_GET and $_POST which one is the fastest?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1924939/2298301)

Comment: Please try debugging the code by adding `print_r($_POST);` and `print_r($_GET);` to see if you're actually receiving the variables in the first place.

Comment: tried it print on the webpage `Array ( ) Array ( [lt] => 14.657575 [ln] => 120.984224 )`

Comment: but on the httprequester `Array ( ) Array ( ) ` is the response

Comment: So when the code on webpage is run, `$lt` and `$ln` should receive `14.657575` and `120.984224` respectively (via `$_POST`), if you `echo` them after the assignment statement. Not sure how `httprequester` is sending the data. It is likely that the variables have not been attached properly to the request.

Comment: The code is working `Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded`

Comment: Great!! Good luck :)