# Using Select form to filter table queried from MySQL using PHP

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, forms, selector

I'm writing some PHP to query from a MySQL database that I have setup on my WAMP server.  I'm also learning PHP and html javascript as I go, so the syntax of both languages is still a little unfamiliar to me.

EDIT: The syntax error has been solved, however I am now receiving a

Undefined index: family

error when I compile.  I am running two files through my server, front.php and back.php.  Front contains a selector form where the user may choose a filter to be applied to the php query to MySQL.  back.php receives the selection with $_REQUEST and uses that in a SELECT query.  I have posted the code relating to the selector form in front.php below.

```
<form method="POST">
<select name="family" onchange="showUser (this.value)">
<option value="empty">Select a Family:</option>
<option value="capacitor">capacitor</option>
<option value="resistor">resistor</option>
<option value="ferrite bead">ferrite bead</option>
</select>
</form>
```

Here is the $_REQUEST call in back.php

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM testv2 WHERE family='".$_REQUEST['family']."'";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
```

Comment: the issue is coming from `$sql="SELECT * FROM testv2 WHERE family ='$_REQUEST['family']'";` look closely

Comment: Side note, that is also subject to sql injection.

Comment: @AkintundeOlawale I've added the periods enclosing .$_REQUEST['family']. if that is what you meant by look closely, but the same syntax error occurs.

Comment: Thanks, figured it out.  However I'm now getting

Undefined index error: family

On the same line

Answer (score 2):

You should change line 24 from:

```php
$sql="SELECT * FROM testv2 WHERE family ='$_REQUEST['family']'";
```

To:

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM testv2 WHERE family ='" . $_REQUEST['family'] . "'";
```

As this should fix the syntax error, but still using the above code is a bad idea, as the code has an SQL Injection vulnerability.

I advice you to use PDO prepared statement if you are learning.
http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php

Answer (score 1):

You are treating

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM testv2 WHERE family ='$_REQUEST['family']'";
```

as an Integer, treat it as a String, do this:

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM testv2 WHERE family ='".$_REQUEST['family']."'";
```

Another suggestion is to use LIKE

Note: LIKE will increase the given results from Database, so be aware of it if you have a lot of data

EDIT: As per the REQUEST, use $_POST directly instead of $_REQUEST, please check  [Among $_REQUEST, $_GET and $_POST](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1924958/9995910)