# How do you map HTTP inputs to functions?

Tags: php, http, get

I have a script, let's call it `myScript.php`. It's one of several scripts.

I want to pass certain things to it via the HTTP address, like this: `…/myScript.php?format=xml&action=courses` where `xml` is the format and the `action` is a query some courses in my database.

But I want also to be able to assign `…/myScript.php?format=json&action=courses` in the same script.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reference any parameters passed in the url like so in php: `$_REQUEST['format']`, `$_REQUEST['actions']`. You can then assign them to a variable and change that variable in your script.

```
fetch('./myScript.php?format=xml&action=courses')

$_REQUEST['format'] //xml
$_REQUEST['actions'] //courses
```

REQUEST is the general method but you can also use GET. Refer to this for more info: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1924958/11945488

Comment: ahhhhhh Wow so simple. Thankye.

Comment: No problem, dont forget to assign the correct answer ;). Good luck!

Comment: You should use `$_GET` instead of `$_REQUEST` if you expect it to be query parameters…

Comment: Added an edit, any particular reason GET is preferred over REQUEST?

Comment: Yes, REQUEST is essentially a merge between GET and POST so for your case you would get the same result

Answer (score 0):

```
$_REQUEST=array_merge($_POST,$_GET,$_COOKIE);
```

in native php global request variable include get post and cookie ..

You should get  parameters with global variable $_GET,
if you does $_REQUEST maybe can confusion php