# POSTing data to JSONP

Tags: wcf, jsonp, http-post

Is it possible to POST data to JSONP? Or does all data have to be passed in the querystring as a GET request? any sample code.

thanks

Comment: Hi Abu, JSONP *cannot* be used for post operations indeed. On a bigger scale it can't even be used as a reliable technology as it's based Javascript emission, which is considered by many as security threat (some hosters won't let you to host webservices which use JSONP). Just out of curiosity - why do you need POST - you can do a 'logical' post by calling get with parameters - say, I can add stuff to the Db and read back its identity no problem. It's not exactly right from the REST ideology point of view, but you know..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using jQuery, try $.post()

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/

Edit: 
More detailed solution here: [How to use getJSON, sending data with post method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/751218/how-to-use-getjson-sending-data-with-post-method)

Comment: From that page: "Due to browser security restrictions, most "Ajax" requests are subject to the same origin policy; the request can not successfully retrieve data from a different domain, subdomain, or protocol." POSTs do not work cross-domain.

Comment: POSTs work cross-domain if the browser, framework, server, etc all support CORS.

Answer (score 6):

No, you can't post data to JSONP. JSONP has to be "submitted" as a script tag, and script tags cannot POST information.

Hope this helps.

Comment: hmmm do you have a sample code how jsonp has to be submitted?

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example:

```
   $.ajax({
        url: ajaxUrl,
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        type: 'GET',
        cache: false,
        success: sCallbackFunction,
        error: eCallbackFunction,
        jsonpCallback: jsonpCallbackFunction,
        data: dataObject
    });
```