# Jquery $.post to php and get back in json format

Tags: jquery, json

Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/751387/2465936)
answer trying to modify jQuery to send data to PHP and get back in JSON format.

Created this

```
$.post(
    "__02.php", 
    {
        'date_day': date_day,
        'currency': currency
    }, 
    function (data, textStatus) {
        $('#currency_load').html(data);
        $('#is_row_changed_currency' + suffix).val(0)
    }, 
    "json"
);
```

PHP is like this

```
 $arr = array ('item1'=>"I love jquery4u",'item2'=>"You love jQuery4u",'item3'=>"We love jQuery4u");
echo json_encode($arr);
```

But does not work. What need to correct?

For comparison without JSON this works:

```
$.post("__02.php", { 'date_day': date_day, 'currency': currency }, function(data) {
    $('#currency_load').html(data);
    $('#is_row_changed_currency' + suffix).val(0)
});
```

`json` is necessary to get following aim

jquery code like

```
$('#div1').html("<p>item1="+data.item1+"</p>");
$('#div2').html("<p>item2="+data.item2+"</p>");
```

`html` like

```
<div id="div1"></div>
<div id="div2"></div>
```

Aim is in certain `id` to display corresponding value/element from php array. Without `json` does not know how to do it. `html` additionally to `div` need to use also `input`. So in `input1` `php` array value[0] and so on

Seems `function (data, textStatus)` must modify to `function (data, success)`

Comment: What's the output of `__02.php`?

Comment: is it showing some error?

Comment: What doesn't work? Be specific. Does it not post? Does it not return? Open up your dev tools (F12 on Chrome) and then make the request, see if there is an error. Look at the "Network" tab to see if it's returning a 404 or some other error, or if the request is being made in the first place (I'm presuming you're using Chrome here, dev tools on any other browser works the same)

Comment: No error. See nothing. If remove `, textStatus` and `, "json"` then all works

Comment: @user2465936 Then remove!!!

Comment: @user2465936 your server is probably not returning valid json then. Make sure there are no other `echo`es or warnings being outputted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing an object (the entire JSON response) to `.html()` which won't work. You need to pick something from the object to display, for example:

```
$( '#currency_load' ).html( data.item1 );
```

If you just want to confirm that the data has been received correctly use [the console](http://www.netmagazine.com/tutorials/javascript-debugging-beginners) instead: `console.log( data )`