# How to send and retrieve information/

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a php file saven on a different domain, and Im using this piece of code to send the username and with that get the info of the user.

Im trying to do something like this, but this is not working is there a way to do it.

```
var dataString = "username="+username+"";
    var url = "";

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: url,
        data: dataString,
        crossDomain: true,
        cache: false,   
        success: $.getJSON(url, function(result)
        {
            console.log(result);
            $.each(result, function(i, field)
            {
                var id       = field.id;
                var username = field.username;
                var email    = field.email;

                $('#profile-info').append("ID: " + id + "<br>Username: " + username + "<br>Email: " + email + "<br><br>"); 
            });
        })
    });
```

Comment: You are using `$.getJSON(` within `$.ajax(` at an impossible point, why?

Comment: use success instead and make sure on your other end cross domain request is on, although it is not recommended.Also .getJSON doesn't work with post request, it is for get

Comment: @JustOnUnderMillions Because I don't know how to do it :/

Comment: see this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/751218/how-to-use-getjson-sending-data-with-post-method

Comment: @adam I did an update on my custion

Comment: see the answer given it is the right one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace the `$.getJSON()` function you have for the `success` calback provided by the jQuery ajax function, and you can pass directly the username through the data parameter as `{ username : username }`, because it's already defined.

Then when you receive successfully your data you can iterate over each result using the jQuery `$.each` function.

Do you really need to set the `cache` parameter to false?, just to know.

Also if you want use `let` instead of `var`, those variables will be just within the `$.each` "block".

```
<script>
  var url = '';

  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: url,
    data: { username: username },
    crossDomain: true,
    cache: false,   
    success: function(result) {
      console.log(result);
      $.each(result, function(i, field) {
        let id = field.id,
          username = field.username,
          email = field.email;

        $('#profile-info').append("ID: " + id + "<br>Username: " + username + "<br>Email: " + email + "<br><br>"); 
      });
    }
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Sebastian Im trying to use your sample, an im getting an error "Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'length' in"

Comment: Can you see the `result` data printed within your `success` callback?

Comment: Yes, the 'response' is success and see the array with the correct values

Comment: Check then how you're handling the received data in the `$.each()` function.

Comment: Thanks sebastian,just need to add JSON.parse