# Help with FQL and List (of T)

Tags: javascript, vb.net, facebook, facebook-fql

I am using the Facebook Toolkit and making a request using FQL.Multiquery.

I am using the following code which returns the correct data:

```
Dim query1 As String = String.Format("SELECT post_id, actor_id, target_id, message FROM stream WHERE source_id in (SELECT target_id FROM connection WHERE source_id={0}) AND is_hidden = 0", FBuserId)
                Dim query2 As String = "SELECT pic FROM user WHERE uid IN (SELECT actor_id FROM #firstQuery)"
                Dim queries = New Dictionary(Of String, String)
                queries.Add("firstQuery", query1)
                queries.Add("secondQuery", query2)
                Dim result As List(Of Facebook.Schema.fql_result) = q.Multiquery(queries)
```

When I run this 'result' list is populated with the results of the two queries in XML but I am unsure how I can send this list to the browser in JSON. I am using asp.net MVC.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

On the Facebook end, you can pass a `format` parameter to tell the FQL call to return JSON instead of XML, [documented here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/).  I'm not sure which Facebook SDK you're using so I can't tell you exactly how to do it, but check that you're passing that parameter in the request (format=json).

As far as the ASP.NET MVC goes, use [the Json method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.json.aspx) to return the data in JSON form.

```
Return Json(result)
```

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/

Here are a few articles that describe how to return JSON on the server-side and read it from the JavaScript side:

- [ASP.NET MVC controller actions that return JSON or partial html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/227624/asp-net-mvc-controller-actions-that-return-json-or-partial-html)
- http://blog.janjonas.net/2011-08-09/asp_net-mvc_3-json-result-jquery-ajax-form-validation