# URL Paths that work with the routing in MVC 3

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

How should I format a path so it works with MVC routing in jQuery?  I'm returning Json, very similar to another [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/227624/asp-net-mvc-controller-actions-that-return-json-or-partial-html).  Everything works great locally, but deployed it just bombs out.  The query runs, but checking firebug it looks like the Success callback for jQuery.Get() doesn't fire.

**LATEST UPDATE**
<s>The only issue I have now is with special characters.  Anytime I pass a "." or "@" as part of the MVC route I get a 404.  Removing these special characters also removes the error.  You can see the Controller and Routing logic below.</s>

*Anytime I pass a '.' as part of the URL it bombs.*  Whats up with the periods?

Queries are of the form
/Service/Index/{email} -

**Broken E.G. /Service/Index/bmackey@foo.com (404)

Working E.G. /Service/Index/bmackeyfoocom (200)**

***Old stuff (for reference)***

I tried `"/Service/Index/email", "../Service/Index/email","../../Service/Index/email"`, but nothing is working.

```
    $email.blur(function ()
        {
            var email = $(this).val(); // grab the value in the input
            var url = '@Url.Action("Index", "Service")';    //this is calling MVC page, not normal aspx so I can't pass it as a query param (at least as far as I am aware)
            $.get(url + '/' + email.toString(),
```

**Update**
I stopped hardcoding my URL.  Local runs work perfectly.  I still get a 404 error when I run on DEV server.  The URL looks correct.  I get a 404 error when I pass a string value, but if I change my parameter to an int I get a returned "null" (with quotes).  This leads me to believe something is wrong with my Controller implementation or routing:

```
    public ActionResult Index(string email)
    {
        string emailAddress = email;

        GetActiveDirectoryInformation adInfo = new GetActiveDirectoryInformation();//calls entity framework
        Common_GetAdInfo_Result result = adInfo.Lookup(email: emailAddress);

        string jsonResponse = System.Web.Helpers.Json.Encode(result);           
        return Json(jsonResponse,JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Global.asax

```
   public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                "Service",
                "Service/Index/{email}",
                new { controller = "Service", action = "Index", email = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
            );

            routes.MapRoute(
                "Default", // Route name
                "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
                new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
            );
```

Comment: use the firebug network tab to see what url is being called, and what the server response is. That should give you a clue.

Comment: Can I ask what you are trying to do? Is this for validation?

Comment: @Paul this is to populate a bunch of employee information given their email address.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Never** hardocde urls like this:

```
var url = '/Service/Index/' + email.toString();
```

Always use URL helpers when dealing with URLs:

```
$email.blur(function () {
    var email = $(this).val(); // grab the value in the input
    var url = '@Url.Action("Index", "Service")';
    $.get(url, { id: email.toString() }, function(result) {
        // ...
    });
});
```

Url helpers will always generate correct urls no matter where your application is deployed.

And if this is a separate javascript file in which you cannot use server side code you could always use HTML5 `data-*` attributes on your input field:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Email, new { data_url = Url.Action("Index", "Service") })
```

and then in your separate javascript file:

```
$email.blur(function () {
    var email = $(this).val(); // grab the value in the input
    var url = $(this).data('url');
    $.get(url, { id: email.toString() }, function(result) {
        // ...
    });
});
```

Comment: does this apply to routing in WebForms?

Comment: You answered my first question.  Creating a new one.

Comment: You can only use URL/HTML Helpers if you are on a razor file, if this is a javascript file you won't have that option.