# jqPlot Chart using asp.net MVC, JSON

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, json, jqplot

I am new to MVC and jQuery and jqPlot.

Can anyone give example where I can find demo projects or step by step procedure to achive.

What I need is:

- How to Return a JSON to view.
- While adding View - it should be partial view or normal view?
- How to get JSON from view using jQuery.
- How to pass JSON object in jqPlot?

Thanks a lot in advance.

===============================================

Tried with below code, it is always going to **ERROR** part, can anyone explain what is the reason?

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]><script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="../Scripts/excanvas.js"></script><![endif]-->
        <script src="../js/jquery-1.3.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" >
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $("#btnClick").click(function () {
                    alert('Inside Click Function');
                    $.ajax(
                        type: 'GET',
                        url: "JSONSample.aspx/GetItSerialized",
                        processData: true,
                        data: {},
                        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                        dataType: "json",
                        success: function (data) {
                            $.each(data.d, function (index, item) {
                                alert('Inside Success');
                            });
                            //alert('Inside Success');
                            //processData(data);
                        },
                        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {alert('Error');}

                    });

                    function processData(data) {
                        alert('test');
                    }
                });
            });
        </script>


    <body>
        <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>  
        <input id="btnClick" runat="server" value="Click here" type="button" />
        </div>
        </form>
    </body>

public string GetItSerialized()
        {
            Employee oEmployee1 = new Employee { Name = "ABC", ID = "111", Age = "30" };
            Employee oEmployee2 = new Employee { Name = "FDF", ID = "rtrt", Age = "31" };
            Employee oEmployee3 = new Employee { Name = "dfdf", ID = "fdfd", Age = "20" };

            List<Employee> listEmp = new List<Employee>
            {
                oEmployee1,
                oEmployee2,
                oEmployee3
            };

            string str = (new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(listEmp));

            return str;
        }

    }

    public class Employee
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Age { get; set; }
        public string ID { get; set; }
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

Well, first of all code you provided is an ASP.NET WebForms sample. 
Tutorials on how to use jqPlot with MVC: [here](http://growingtech.blogspot.com/2012/06/jqplot-line-with-aspnet-mvc-3.html) or [here](http://growingtech.blogspot.com/2012/06/jqplot-bar-graph-with-aspnet-mvc-3.html). 
To answer rest of your questions:

1. *How to return JSON to a View?* 
    See answer no. 4
2. *While adding View - it should be partial view or normal view?* 
    It really depends on what you are trying to accomplish. If you want to create something like a widget then use partial views.
3. *How to get JSON from view using jQuery?* 
    I'm not really sure what do you mean.
4. *How to pass JSON object to jqPlot?* 
    Call controller action that will return json object. Follow this [Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/227624/asp-net-mvc-controller-actions-that-return-json-or-partial-html) with this [tutorial](http://www.jqplot.com/deploy/dist/examples/data-renderers.html)