# Adding Changes Saved Javascript Popup

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

This is a MVC3 project using razor. Instead of displaying another view to inform the user that the changes have been saved successfully I would like to simply fire a JavaScript popup informing them... Everything I have found on the web either opens a whole new browser window, or misses what I am trying to accomplish all together... I know there is a simpler way to go about doing this but this is where I am... At the end of the controller function that does the save on the return I simply use redirect and send it to another controller function that displays a screen saying "Changes Have Been Saved Successfully" then the user clicks a button there which will take them back to the index page... IMO this is a bit shotty and think it can be cleaned up through the use of Javascript...I have not found any luck on this yet.. Currently the below code is what I am using:

```
 Function SomeFunctionName()
       db.SaveChanges()
       Return RedirectToAction(ChangesSaved)
 End Function

 Function ChangesSaved()
       Return View()
 End Function
```

And the javascript that I have implemented in the `ChangesSaved` view.

```
@Code
ViewData("Title") = "ChangesSaved"
End Code
<script type="text/javascript">
      alert("Changes Have Been Saved Successfully");
</script>
```

There are a few problems with this though...

[image: JavaScript]

How do I tell the javascript When the user clicks OK it should take them to another page.

I did just try the below and since I am very new to java/javascript it failed:

```
  var r=alert("Changes Have Been Saved Successfully");
if (r == true) {
@html.Action("***********","Admin")
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I were you I would post your form using Jquery. Then you can set a callback. In Mvc you can return JSON data, a simple value indicating that the save worked would be enough. Then you can call your alert although you might consider using a jQuery UI dialog as it's way more flexible. If you haven't ever used jQuery I wouldn't be afraid, it's easy and there is a lot of great examples out there.

Take a look at this http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/ and this, [ASP.NET MVC controller actions that return JSON or partial html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/227624/asp-net-mvc-controller-actions-that-return-json-or-partial-html)

Comment: Let me know if you need more code examples with this but it I am guessing you can probably get all you need from those two links above.