# How to retrieve list of strings in jquery at client side

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have a list at my Home controller that is :

```
public List<string> BoomList()
        {
            List<string> BoomList = new List<string>()
            {
                "Rohit", "Harish", "Vivek"
            };

            return BoomList;
        }
```

I want to use the BoomList values at client side using jquery like :

```
<script type="text/jscript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#ButtonID").click(function () {
            var url = "/Home/BoomList";
            $.get(url, null, function (data) {// data is the list

                $("label[for=lblName]").text(data); // How to iterate data here?
            });
        })
    });
</script>
```

How to iterate through my list(data) here?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/227624/asp-net-mvc-controller-actions-that-return-json-or-partial-html ?

Comment: What is expected result of `data` iteration ?

Comment: data is list object, i want to know how to iterate it over here?

Comment: You can use [jquery each](http://api.jquery.com/each/) to iterate resulted list. See my answer with working demo [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26333358/how-to-retrieve-list-of-strings-in-jquery-at-client-side/26333776#26333776)

Answer (score 0):

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/5m31kzbf/1/)**

You can use following to iterate returned list. Let say that you have a div with and id `lblDivs` that surrounds labels;

```
<div id="lblDivs"></div>
```

And Js code in ajax success return will be;

```
$.each(data, function(k, v) {
    $("<label for=lbl" + k + ">").text(v).appendTo("#lblDivs");
});
```

I have concat list id with label name in order to prevent duplicate for names. You need to give name to related element to those label if exists.

Answer (score 0):

Your method at controller will return string...  and you have to serialize list to string and return that string like:

```
public string BoomList()
{
    List<string> BoomList = new List<string>()
    {
        "Rohit", "Harish", "Vivek"
    };

    return Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObjectAsync(BoomList).Result;
}
```

and at client end you will have to parse it to JSON and then you can iterate like this:

```
$.ajax({
   url: "/Home/BoomList",
   type: 'get',
   success: function (data) {
      var isValidJson = IsJson(data);
      if (isValidJson) {
      var jsonObj = $.parseJSON(data);

         if (jsonObj != null) {
            $.each(jsonObj, function(i){
            alert(jsonObj[i]);
         });
      }
   }

}
});

function IsJson(str) {
try {
    JSON.parse(str);
} catch (e) {
    return false;
}
return true;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

U can use popular 'underscore js' javascript library from www.underscorejs.org

_.each(data, function(element, index, list) {
  dosomething with element....
}

)

_.each is one of 100 functions offered by underscore library.
U can include underscore via visual studio nuget package manager and search for underscore.js